# Trouble naming csv file I'm writing a dataframe to in pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble setting the name of a dataframe that I'm trying to write to a csv file.

```
def write_csv(df):
  os.makedirs('Output_csv_files', exist_ok=True)
  df.to_csv(f"{df}.csv")
  return print("Success!")
```

This is making the *contents* of the dataframe the name of it rather than the name of the variable itself. For example, if my df's name is "walmart_df," it wouldn't name the csv file "walmart_df.csv" but rather "[whatever the contents of the dataframe are].csv". How can I fix this?

Comment: Thanks for this @Stefan - this is really interesting but I get a syntax error when I try it. Is it possible that it works for dicts but not for dataframes?

Comment: how about using `df.name`?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58451182/14311263) answer?

Comment: Thanks for pointing here @Timus, this is really interesting but I get a syntax error when I try it. Is it possible that it works for dicts but not for dataframes?

Comment: @Aaron Works for me with dataframes. What kind of syntax error do you get?