# List with full dictionary name and key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary named `Asset_Class` — the keys are the following:

```
dict_keys(['Equity Fund', 'Structure Products', 'Unclassified', 'Equity', 'Alternatives', 
           'Derivatives', 'Fixed Income'])
```

I need to create a list as per below

```
listt = [Asset_Class['Equity'], Asset_Class['Equity Fund'], Asset_Class['Fixed Income']]
```

How can I create a loop to populate the list with the full dictionary name and key?

Comment: is `listt` not a list? what's the problem?

Comment: Adding onto what @enke said, could you provide concrete input / outputs for what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you just trying to get a list of the values? then `Asset_Class.values()` should get you what you want

Comment: You can't create a list that has the name of the dictionary and key like that. It would be possible to create one that had the value associated with each one of those keys in the `Asset_Class` dictionary — is that what you meant?

Comment: The name the dictionary is assigned to will be one of the keys in `locals()`  but I don't know how you would go about deciding which one.

Comment: Possibly related: [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `list` containing all the `key`/`value` pairs in the `dict`?

```
listt = [Asset_Class['Equity'], Asset_Class['Equity Fund'], Asset_Class['Fixed Income']]
```

Use the `dict.items()` method, like this:

```
listt = []
for key, value in Asset_Class.items():
    listt.append(key)
    listt.append(value)
```

---

This is the result:

```
>>> dictionary = {"key": "value"}
>>> print(dictionary.items())
dict_items([('key', 'value')])
>>> listt = []
>>> for key, value in dictionary.items():
        listt.append(key)
        listt.append(value)
>>> print(listt)
['key', 'value']
```

Comment: If you are trying to store the key-value pairs I think you mean to use `dict.items()` rather than `dict.values()`

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you want to achieve (and whether it's even possible). Here are a couple of ways of creating a list that contain elements that *are* possible — they both create the result using something called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) which is a very succinct method of creating lists programmatically.

Note that none of the list contain the name of the full dictionary (`Asset_Class`) as you have in your question (because that's impossible).

```
Asset_Class = {
    'Equity Fund': 'value1',
    'Structure Products': 'value2',
    'Unclassified': 'value3',
    'Equity': 'value4',
    'Alternatives': 'value5',
    'Derivatives': 'value6',
    'Fixed Income': 'value7'
}

# First possibility.
listt = [Asset_Class[key] for key in ('Equity', 'Equity Fund', 'Fixed Income')]
print(listt)  # -> ['value4', 'value1', 'value7']

# Second possibility.
listt = [(key, value) for key, value in Asset_Class.items()
            if key in ('Equity', 'Equity Fund', 'Fixed Income')]
print(listt)  # -> [('Equity Fund', 'value1'), ('Equity', 'value4'), ('Fixed Income', 'value7')]
```