# Equivalent implementation using f-strings and eval

Tags: python, f-string

```
x = type.__dict__
x is x
```

gives,

```
True
```

but,

```
x = type.__dict__
operator = 'is'
eval(f'{x} {operator} {x}')
```

gives,

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

even,

```
operator = 'is'
eval(f'{x!r} {operator} {x!r}')
```

gives,

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how to get `True` as output using eval and f-strings?

Comment: `eval('x is x')`?

Comment: assume the operator is not fixed, so, I have to use f-string for it.

Comment: then `eval(f'x {operator} x'}`

Comment: `x is x` does not give `False`.

Comment: sorry, my bad, changed it. the `eval(f'x {operator} x')` is working for now, thanks. @Steve

Answer (score 0):

When using eval you are executing exactly what you wrote in the string. By formatting with the curly brakets you are inserting in the string the value of "x", or at least whatever is returned by the "`__str__`" method of x.

```
print(f"{x}")
```

gives

```
{'__repr__': <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'type' objects>, '__call__': <slot wrapper '__call__' of 'type' objects>, '__getattribute__': <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'type' objects>, '__setattr__': <slot wrapper '__setattr__' of 'type' objects>, '__delattr__': <slot wrapper '__delattr__' of 'type' objects>, '__init__': <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'type' objects>, '__new__': <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x908780>, 'mro': <method 'mro' of 'type' objects>, '__subclasses__': <method '__subclasses__' of 'type' objects>, '__prepare__': <method '__prepare__' of 'type' objects>, '__instancecheck__': <method '__instancecheck__' of 'type' objects>, '__subclasscheck__': <method '__subclasscheck__' of 'type' objects>, '__dir__': <method '__dir__' of 'type' objects>, '__sizeof__': <method '__sizeof__' of 'type' objects>, '__basicsize__': <member '__basicsize__' of 'type' objects>, '__itemsize__': <member '__itemsize__' of 'type' objects>, '__flags__': <member '__flags__' of 'type' objects>, '__weakrefoffset__': <member '__weakrefoffset__' of 'type' objects>, '__base__': <member '__base__' of 'type' objects>, '__dictoffset__': <member '__dictoffset__' of 'type' objects>, '__mro__': <member '__mro__' of 'type' objects>, '__name__': <attribute '__name__' of 'type' objects>, '__qualname__': <attribute '__qualname__' of 'type' objects>, '__bases__': <attribute '__bases__' of 'type' objects>, '__module__': <attribute '__module__' of 'type' objects>, '__abstractmethods__': <attribute '__abstractmethods__' of 'type' objects>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'type' objects>, '__doc__': <attribute '__doc__' of 'type' objects>, '__text_signature__': <attribute '__text_signature__' of 'type' objects>}
```

Meaning that's what you are trying to execute, which is indeed invalid syntax.

You should instead do:

```
eval("x is x")
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```py
>>> d = {"a":42}
{'a': 42}
>>> print(f"{d} is {d}")
{'a': 42} is {'a': 42}
>>> {'a': 42} is {'a': 42}
False
>>> eval(f"{d} is {d}")
False
```

This works just fine with dicts.

However, calling `str.__dict__` returns something completely different than you'd probably expect:

```py
>>> str.__dict__
mappingproxy({
   '__new__': <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFC55D1AC60>,
   '__repr__': <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'str' objects>,
   --- snip for readability ---
```

This "dict-representation" is actually a `MappingProxy` as you can verify with `type(str.__dict__)` and cannot exactly be re-interpreted by `eval()` as `<built-in method __new__...` is obviously a syntax error, when used without quotes. You can easily verify this by pasting this into a Python interpreter:

```py
>>> {"myKey": <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFC55D1AC60>}

File "<stdin>", line 1
  {"myKey": <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x00007FFC55D1AC60>}
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What you're trying to do requires not only `type` (whatever this might be at runtime) to have a dict-representation, but also every member to have one - recursively! This is hard to assume in a general case.

I'm convinced what you're trying to achieve can be done using a different way - if you want elaborate your task at hand, there might be a more suitable way.

If you insist on the `eval()` way, take a look at `repr()` and `eval()`, as generally, `repr` tries to produce a string, which can be fed into `eval` to produce the very same object again.
However, this is possible **only**, if the object implements `repr` to do exactly that - which is not guaranteed. There might be objects which cannot be serialized that way.

```py
myDict = {"myKey": "myVal"}
myDict == eval(repr(myDict))
# Output: True
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the same as `x is x` through eval you need the **name** of the variable as a string "x" instead of the variable itself. How to get it is answered here: [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-stringc)

Here is a solution for your case:

```
x = type.__dict__
operator = 'is'
x_name = f'{x=}'.split('=')[0]

eval(f'{x_name} {operator} {x_name}')
```

Resulting in:

```
> True
```