# How to print an existing variable by passing its name

Tags: python

For example:

```
class abc():
    def __init__(self):
        self.john = 'a'
        self.mike = 'b'

    def d(self, x):
        print(self.x)

m = abc()
# m.d('john')
# m.d(john)
```

If I try running m.d('john') I get 'AttributeError: 'abc' object has no attribute 'x'' and if I try running m.d(john) I get 'NameError: name 'john' is not defined'. How can I modify this so that it works?

Comment: [Here is a solution from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: Did you actually try that?  I think you'll be disappointed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getattr()`. It allows you to get an attribute from a string.

Code:

```
class abc():
    def __init__(self):
        self.john = 'a'
        self.mike = 'b'

    def d(self, x):
        print(getattr(self, x))

m = abc()
m.d('john')
```

Output:

```
a
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Python's [`getattr()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/getattr).

```
class abc():
    def __init__(self):
        self.john = 'a'
        self.mike = 'b'

    def d(self, x):
        print(getattr(self, x))

m = abc()
m.d('john')
```

Comment: what are the chances we wrote the exact same code at the exact same time with the exact same first name LOL

Comment: Non-zero, obviously!

Comment: This should go on some Stack Overflow hall-of-fame. I'm willing to bet that this is the first time this has happened.