# Get name of List Item in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of dataframes in python.

sensors = [df_x, df_y, df_z]

df_x, df_y, df_z are dataframes

**How to get name of the dataframe?**

Ex: df_x, df_y, df_z

Comment: Isn't `df_x` just a variable? what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Python variables are not the names *of* objects, just names your code uses to *refer* to objects. The objects themselves don't know what variables refer to them, only how *many* references to them exist.

Comment: Rather then a list of dataframes you could have a dictionary of dataframes with the keys being the intended names of the dataframes.

Comment: those are not the "names" of the dataframes. Those are just variables that happen to refer to those dataframes. If you want to associate a string with a dataframe, you should create a data structure that makes that association directly, e.g. a `dict` or even a list of `tuple`s

Answer (score 0):

```
df_x = ['df_x', (variable)]
df_y = ['df_x', (variable)]    
df_z = ['df_x', (variable)]  
sensors = [df_x[1], df_y[1], df_z[1]]
```

if you want to know variable name in string, df_x[0] is that one.

Answer (score 0):

If a variable starts with df_ is a dataframe to you. You can use this.

```py
# If the values of the list are strings
sensors = ['df_x', 'df_y', 'df_z']

for i in sensors:
    if i.startswith("df_"):
        print(f"{i} is a dataframe")
    print(f'{i} is not a dataframe')
```

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments you can't know the name of the df, as in the name of the df-object in your code (atleast not without using some [dodgy python magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18425523/623735)).

But if you can modify the df's while you still know what you want to call them, there actually is a way without storing the name and df separately in a dict or tuple as was suggested. You can name the df directly by using a custom attribute:

```
import pandas as pd


df_x = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b'])
df_x.attrs['name'] = 'df_x'

print(df_x)
print(f"Name of df_x: {df_x.attrs.get('name', None)}")
```

Gives the output:

```
Name of df_x: df_x
```

You could do exactly the same by saving and retrieving the name through `df.name` (or using any other like `df.h9d32` for that matter) but if there is a column `name` (resp. `h9d32`) in your dataframe it would overwrite it. Using `.attrs` is safer in this regard.