# Python variable value as it's name

Tags: python, variables

I am writing code and I wonder how to approach following issue - I want to use variable name in it's value (concatenating with other string for example). For example

```
variable_01 = 'some_text_variable_01'
variable_02 = 'some_text_variable_02'
```

when variables are strings, having its names in these strings.

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this technique?

Comment: Isn't it doable in the way that I proposed?

Comment: @ScottHunter in fact I am trying to get part of variable name and then execute a function based on it's name and return a string from a list and assign to the value of this variable.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string) is probably what you should be looking at

Comment: this seems somewhat redundant with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string you might find the discussion there useful

Comment: " I want to use variable name in it's value" *don't do this*. Just use an appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your are best to use a dictionary for what you want to do.

For example,
If you have a script that produces a list of strings. Then you would have the function as such:

```
x=["var1","var2","var3"]
fd={}
for y in x:
   string=f"some_text_{y}"
    fd[y]=string
```

this will give you a dictionary that then contains the "variable" and string pair.

Answer (score 0):

Many people are going to correctly point out that a dictionary is likely what you really want to use.  However, there is a way to do what you seek by leveraging the dictionary provided by `globals()`.

While I do not recommend it, this is technically possible:

```py
name = "variable_01"
globals()[name] = f"some_text_{name}"
print(variable_01)
```

Your IDE will likely complain about it, but when you run that you should see:

`some_text_variable_01`

Answer (score -1):

I got it working!

```
pip install varname
```

then:

```
from varname import varname

def func():
  return varname()

variable_01 = func()
print(variable_01)
```

and the result of executing the script:

```
C:/Users/some_user/.../Python311/python.exe c:/Users/some_user/project/test_varname.py

variable_01
```