# Python using the {} method in loop for variable names

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list

`test=['num1' ,'num2']`

and variables

```
valuenum1 = 'x'
valuenum2 = 'y'
```

I want to do the following loop

```
for i in test:
       print(value{i})
```

Which I cant do because value is not a string, so the {i} method is useless. Is there a way to do loop the value in `test` so I can print `valuenum1` and `valuenum2`?

Comment: You don't want variables named like that. You want a single dict like `values = {'num1': 'x', 'num2': 'y'}`.

Comment: If you're bound and determined to make this work for a very good reason, have a look at [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string) but there are better ways to store and access your data