How to dynamically initialize a variable according to the object's creating method in python?
class obj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ...  # How to set this variable dynaically by using the variable name (on create) or the object name?


var = obj()
print(var.name)  # should print "var" (assigned variable name), but how???

print(obj().name)  # prints "obj" when changing the ellipsis into self.__class__.__name__

Currently, both of them prints "obj".
How can I set self.name according to the way the obj object is created?
Example: I wish to print "var" when I write var = obj(); print(var.name), while it should print "obj" at print(obj().name)
One more thing: I don't want to pass in the variable name as an argument, but automate the whole process.
Logics:
if obj is assigned as a variable called var -> self.name = "var"
else: -> self.name = self.__class__.__name__

I viewed this post before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string, but the searching approach focused on values, while I focus on abstract objects.

Suppose you do objects = []; objects.append(obj()); print(objects[0].name), what do you want it to print?

What value should it have?

This gives the same result as before. We need to change the Ellipsis into something else, that prints different stuff based on the object's declaration. Like, it should print "var" when I write var = obj(); print(var.name), while it should print "obj" at print(obj().name).

Both objects are created in exactly the same way - by calling obj().  Whether or not the object is later assigned to a variable cannot have any possible effect on the object creation.

Does this answer your question? Getting an instance name inside class __init__()

Well, partially...
It gives this
"var" for the first situation, correct
"""print(obj().name)  # prints "obj""" for the second situation, doesn't work

Can you explain why you want this? The linked question gives a hack how this might work, but it's super ugly and brittle. Also, what if var1 = var2 = obj()? Is this purely "out of interest", or for debugging, or do you have some productive use in mind?

Can you clarify what you want it to print in the example I gave in my previous comment?

If you want this for debug output, then something like this might make more sense.

I try to answer the question only to discourage you from pursuing your idea, at the moment the reasons you have given do not justify the goal you want to achieve.
Implement the __call__ method with the task to get the variable identifier from the global namespace otherwise set a default.
Limitations: it needs to be "called" twice and for multiple instances pointing to the same object (but each with a different identifier) then the oldest (in order of execution) is used.
class obj:

    def __call__(self):
        for k, v in dict(globals()).items():
            if isinstance(v, type(self)):
                if id(v) == id(self):
                    setattr(self, 'name', k)
                    break
        else:
            setattr(self, 'name', type(self).__name__)

        return self


# case 0
var0 = obj()()
print(var0.name)
#obj

# case 1
var1 = obj()
var1()
print(var1.name)
#var1

# case 2
var2 = obj()
print(var2().name)
#var2

# case 3
print(obj()().name)
#obj

# case 4
var3 = obj()
var4 = obj()
print(var3().name)
#var3

# case 5
var5 = var1
print(var5.name)
#var1

I would recommend to use a kind of dictionary approach.

technically, it's not mandatory to use __call__, any method works fine... but with __call__ you need to write less

Building upon the method by Cards, but using a lazily evaluated @property for the name attribute...
 class obj:

    def __init__(self, name=None):
        self._name = name

    @property
    def name(self):
        if self._name is None:
            self._name = next(
                (k for k, v in dict(globals()).items() if v is self),
                type(self).__name__
            )
        return self._name

var1 = obj("foo")
var2 = obj()
print(var1.name, var2.name, obj().name)
# foo var2 obj


Nice filter condition!

You can define name here and call it when declaring object like
class obj(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

var = obj("Hello World")

print(obj.name) # output "Hello World"

or
somestr = "random string"

var2 = obj(somestr)

print(var2) # output "random string"


Good idea! But I actually want self.name to automate itself, rather than passing the name as an argument explicitly.
