# Convert python statement to string

Tags: python, class, object

I have a `class` which is instantiated into an object.  I would like to be able to generate a string, when I change any of the object's property. The string must contain the objects Name, the property's Name and the value that it changed to:

```
class Common(object):
    pass

Obj = Common()
Obj.Name = 'MyName'
Obj.Size = 50
print Obj.Size
>50
Obj.Size = 100
```

I would like to have a string containing "Obj,Size,100"
Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, my mistake

Comment: Consider also overriding `__repr__` or `__str__`. Overriding the first special method I mentioned will work everywhere where you will "present" your object eg. in echo in IDLE. Overriding the second one will change behavior of your objects in `print` function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `get_size` class method as follows:

```
class Common(object):

    def get_size(self):
        return "Obj,Size,{}".format(self.size)

obj = Common()
obj.name = 'MyName'
obj.size = 50
print(obj.get_size())
```

**Output**

```
Obj,Size,50
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants. And if he create two `Common` object? They will be declared with different names and the "Obj" in the returned string will not be good anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for special methods, namely `__setattr__()` to perform actions on attribute change, i.e.:

```
>>> class Common(object):
...     pass
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...         print("Name: {}, Value: {}".format(name, value))
...         object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
... 
>>> obj=Common()
>>> obj.test=10

Name: test, Value: 10
```

This way anytime you add some attribute to object it'll be printed. See docs for more information: https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: Almost there. How do I get the name of the Object as well ?

Comment: Actually, there's no straight way to get instance name, unlike class name, because instance name is just a reference to memory block, unlike class name which represents a type. However, it can be done by inspecting the stack with `traceback` or `inspect`, i.e. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690400/getting-an-instance-name-inside-class-init. Though, it's more common to have a name attribute and assign it in constructor when creating an instance, and then use it when needed, i.e. in `__repr__` or `__str__`.