# print object name, when object call a function inside the class

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
class AA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def y(self):
        pass

x=AA()
x.y()
```

When I execute x.y(), I want to print "This is 'x' call me", how should I do it ?

Comment: Are you looking for the variable name x? should be printed?

Comment: Just replace `pass` inside `y()` with `print("This is 'x' call me")`

Comment: Objects do not and cannot know their names.

Comment: I think you're confusing variables with objects.

Comment: no, I just want to now which objects are calling this function

Comment: no, I just want to now which objects are calling this function, we can some name conventions(vm1 vm2, vm3..) for writing code for example, we have lots of vm instance,vm1=AA(), vm1.run_cmd("xxxx"), vm2=AA(), vm2.run_cmd("") I want to know which vm are run some cmd

Comment: may be you could have added your multiple VM scenario to question!...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print object/instance name in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599015/print-object-instance-name-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I hope that this will solve your issue

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


class AA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def y(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print("This is %s call me" % name)


x = AA()
x.y("Tarzan")
```

Comment: I really don't want to pass a parameter to get this, "x" is already there, i think there should be a way to print it out

Comment: @user1334609 no, there's none. The `AA` instance referenced by name `x` knows _nothing_ about `x`. Believe it or not but this is the best answer you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is an object in Python, When you create an instance of the class it allocate memory location and that memory location is referenced by your x variable.The only object has memory location, variable doesn't have any memory location. Variable just refer to objects memory location

in your example, **X** is nothing just reference to your memory location

if  define a variable

```
a = 2
```

that means **a** reference to 2

```
a = 1
```

that means a now reference to 1

Assigning one variable to another makes a new tag bound to the same value as shown below.

```
b = a
```

that means **a and b** both reference to 1

id() in python return memory location

```
print id(a)
print id(b)
```

**output**

```
140621897573617
140621897573617
```

**Example 1**:

```
>>> s1 = 'hello'

>>> s2 = 'hello'

>>> id(s1), id(s2) 
(4454725888, 4454725888)

>>> s1 == s2 True

>>> s1 is s2 True

>>> s3 = 'hello, world!'

>>> s4 = 'hello, world!'

>>> id(s3), id(s4) (4454721608, 4454721664)

>>> s3 == s4 True

>>> s3 is s4 False
```

**Example 2**

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
...
>>> bar = Foo()
>>> baz = Foo()
>>> id(bar)
140730612513248
>>> id(baz)
140730612513320
```

**result**

> Name of object or instance is nothing just reference to memory
>   location

Comment: no, I just want to now which objects are calling this function, we can some name conventions(vm1 vm2, vm3..) for writing code  for example, we have lots of vm instance,vm1=AA(), vm1.run_cmd("xxxx"), vm2=AA(), vm2.run_cmd("") I want to know which vm are run some cmd

Comment: ID is not readable, I actually want to show this info in the log to make it sense

Comment: @user1334609, do you want to show vm's name in log or you want to show variable's name in log.? I feel vm's name would be more appropriate.

Comment: @user1334609 you can read memory address by using Ctype module in Python if you want exact name then you have to create instance with id or name

Comment: @Haranadh I want to use variable as the vm name, I ask people to use a self-explanation name as variable name, I don't want to pass extra parameter here

Comment: How to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

From @user1334609 's comment:

> for example, we have lots of vm instance,vm1=AA(),
>   vm1.run_cmd("xxxx"), vm2=AA(), vm2.run_cmd("") I want to know which vm
>   are run some cmd

To know which VM has run the command you can just use the `id(self)`, instead of trying to find the declared variable in code.

Two options you have now to see from which vm, command is running.

**Option1:** Add a member variable to class. This can give readability.

**Option2:** Use the `id` of `self` in `y()`. This avoids adding additional variable.

Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
class AA(object):
    def __init__(self, vmname):
        self.whoami = vmname

    def y(self):
        print "My Name is %s " % self.whoami # Option1
        print "My Id is %s " % id(self) # Option2


def main():
    vm1=AA("Yoda")
    vm1.y()
    vm2=AA("Boda")
    vm2.y()
    vm3=AA("Anakin")
    vm3.y()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This gives following output:

```
My Name is Yoda 
My Id is 139725977256656 
My Name is Boda 
My Id is 139725977256720 
My Name is Anakin 
My Id is 139725977256784
```

Comment: I really want to avoid using parameters

Comment: @user1334609, If dont want to use parameters, then inside `y(self)` you could check the id of self, which would help you identifying from which `vm` object call happens. Means you could choose option2.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a complete solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331683/7386061

It works without parameters. For example you could just do:

```
class AA(RememberInstanceCreationInfo):
    def y(self):
        print("my name is '"+self.creation_name+"'")

x=AA()
x.y()
out: my name is 'x'
```