# How to tell a Python Exception where the function that raised it came from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, traceback

Suppose I write a simple Python class, `Delay`, whose point is to encapsulate a delayed (lazy) computation:

```py
class Delay:
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        self.partial = (fn, args, kwargs)
        self.result = None
    def __call__(self):
        if self.partial is not None:
            (fn, args, kwargs) = self.partial
            self.result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            self.partial = None
        return self.result
```

This is straightforward enough, but now let's think about how it will be used:

```py
# Somewhere in some initialization module of the codebase:
def load_historical_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)
def init_runtime(param_dict):
    ...
    # (Prepare to) load some data that won't be needed right away.
    runtime['historical_data'] = Delay(load_historical_data,
                                       param_dict['hist_filename'])
    ...
    return runtime

# Some far remote corner of the codebase...
def _analyze_history_job_firstpass(runtime, kwargs*):
    ...
    histdata = runtime['historical_data']()
    ...
```

One problem with the above paradigm arises when there is a bug in the `init_runtime` function—for example, if the `param_dict['hist_filename']` isn't a valid filename. In this case, when `_analyze_history_job_firstpass` eventually gets called, it will raise an exception due to the file not being found, but nothing about that exception will point back to `init_runtime`, which makes debugging difficult.

It would be ideal if the `Delay` class could detect the exception during its `__call__` method and instead raise an alternate exception that documented both the call stack that created `fn` and the call stack that called `fn`. How can one achieve this? (If there are multiple ways, what are the advantages/disadvantages of each?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arguably friendlier approach would be to produce a forced exception and save it into the object during initialization, and then raise the saved exception when handling an exception that actually occurs during the execution of the delayed call:

```
class Delay:
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        self.partial = (fn, args, kwargs)
        self.result = None
        try:
            # artificially create an exception that can be re-raised later
            raise ValueError(f'{fn.__name__} failed with args {args} and kwargs {kwargs}')
        except ValueError as e:
            self.init_exception = e

    def __call__(self):
        if self.partial is not None:
            (fn, args, kwargs) = self.partial
            try:
                self.result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception:
                # raise the saved exception
                raise self.init_exception
            self.partial = None
        return self.result

def load_historical_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return f.read()

def init_runtime(filename):
    runtime = Delay(load_historical_data, filename)
    return runtime

def _analyze_history_job_firstpass(runtime):
    return runtime()

_analyze_history_job_firstpass(init_runtime('foobar'))
```

This produces an error output with tracebacks of both the call stack that created `fn` and the call stack that called `fn`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in __call__
    self.result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 23, in load_historical_data
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foobar'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
    _analyze_history_job_firstpass(init_runtime('foobar'))
  File "main.py", line 31, in _analyze_history_job_firstpass
    return runtime()
  File "main.py", line 18, in __call__
    raise self.init_exception
  File "main.py", line 7, in __init__
    raise ValueError(f'{fn.__name__} failed with args {args} and kwargs {kwargs}')
ValueError: load_historical_data failed with args ('foobar',) and kwargs {}
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/PassionateKnowingAlgorithms#main.py

Answer (score 1):

If I understood question correctly, you want to get callstack or traceback of exceptions from `init_runtime` and analyze it in `_analyze_history_job_firstpass`. (Or did you want to aggregate multiple exceptions?)

Here are some alternatives I can think of:

1. creating decorator ([another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51645244/stackable-decorator-using-a-traceback-to-obtain-caller-name-of-function-class))
2. make caller log/get/send traceback in exception
3. validate file path first and log/get/send traceback in exception

#### custom decorator

```py
import traceback
from functools import wraps

def trace(orig_func):
    @wraps(orig_func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        trace = traceback.format_exc()
        _analyze_history_job_firstpass(trace)
        return trace
        
    return wrapper
  
 class Delay:
    @trace
    def foo(self):
        return
```

#### caller does the job

```py
def init_runtime(param_dict):
    
    try:
        runtime['historical_data'] = Delay(load_historical_data,
                                           param_dict['hist_filename'])
    except Exception:
        trace = traceback.format_exc()
        logger.warn(trace)
        _analyze_history_job_firstpass(trace)
    
    return runtime
```

I'd like to know more details about your intention then i can think of better ways.