# Python switch between pretty print and plain print in __repr__()

Tags: python, printing

I would like to have a class

```
class Test:
    def __repr__(self):
        if self in a list/set:
            return self.__class__.__name__
        else:
            return 'My pretty print like Numpy/Tensorflow'
```

that is able to have an "adaptive" `__repr__()`. When I simply print the instance, it should print the pretty print.

```
a = Test()
a
'My pretty print like Tensorflow/numpy'
```

When I put the object in a list and print the list, it just shows the object name.

```
b = Test()
z = [a, b]
z
[a, b]
```

I need this feature because normally printing `z` will give `['My pretty print like Tensorflow/numpy', 'My pretty print like Tensorflow/numpy']` which looks ugly.

---

My attempt: use garbage collector to know if the object is in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You can't reliably detect if your object is referenced by a container object and that your `__repr__` is being called to produce the `__repr__` output of that container.

That's because your object can be referenced by *any number of other objects*. The container object might have an internal data structure that holds the reference, the `__repr__` implementation will have a temporary reference, your object could be referenced by multiple containers, etc. Next, detecting that you are actually being called as part of a `__repr__` call for the parent container could easily fail because your `__repr__` value could be cached, or could be part of some intermediate object that itself is only created as a utility object to produce that output.

Libraries like numpy and tensorflow instead have their own container formats where the special output they produce is *part of that container*, and *not* part of the classes whose instances are contained.

If you want to produce 'nice' human readable output, define `__str__` and use `print(yourobject)`. `__repr__` is there to produce debug-friendly output.

Comment: Indeed. `__str__()` can be used for pretty print instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing around with garbage collector, just make a PrettyList subclass that does this and use that:

```
class PrettyList(list):
    def __str__(self):
        return str([str(x) for x in self])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `traceback` module to get the instance's variable name, and you can use the `inspect` module to find out the stack trace of the `__repr__` call. That way, you can figure out if it was a list which ended up calling the representation, or just by calling `__repr__` directly.

If you put it all together, you get something like this:

```py
import traceback
import inspect

# Class definition
class Test:

    # Initialization
    def __init__(self):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/1690751/11985743
        (filename,line_number, function_name,text) = traceback.extract_stack()[-2]
        # Get the variable name
        self.defined_name = text[:text.find('=')].strip()

    # Representation
    def __repr__(self):
        # For each stack call
        for stack_call in inspect.stack():
            # If the code that called it is the same code to represent lists
            if stack_call.code_context:
                if stack_call.code_context[0].strip() == "p.pretty(x)":
                    # Then it was represented in a list, so return the defined name
                    return self.defined_name
        # Otherwise, it was represented directly, so return the proper representation
        return 'My pretty print like Numpy/Tensorflow'
```

And if you try running a test case:

```
In : z = Test()

In : z
Out: My pretty print like Numpy/Tensorflow

In : [z]
Out: [z]
```

Comment: `traceback` is a higher-level user of `sys._getframe()`. You **can't rely on this**, there is no guarantee that the variable you find actually references your object and how this is connected to a `__repr__` call that outputs a string containing your object `__repr__`.

Comment: And there is no guarantee of an assignment statement _either_, e.g. `globals().update({"foo": Test()})` would create or replace the global name `foo` with a new instance of `Test()` assigned to it.