# How to print the variable name

Tags: python, variables, printing

I've designed a code that calculates the percentage of 'CG' appears in a string; GC_content(DNA).

Now I can use this code so that it prints the the value of the string with the highest GC-content;

```
print (max((GC_content(DNA1)),(GC_content(DNA2)),(GC_content(DNA3)))).
```

Now how would I get to print the variable name of this max GC_content?

Comment: To access a list of names in the global namespace you can use `globals()`.

Comment: Variable name is not generally printable, see [retrieving a variable's name in python at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932818/retrieving-a-variables-name-in-python-at-runtime), but the answers here give some nice workarounds.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the `max` of some tuples:

```
max_content, max_name = max(
    (GC_content(DNA1), "DNA1"),
    (GC_content(DNA2), "DNA2"),
    (GC_content(DNA3), "DNA3")
)

print(max_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have many DNA variables you could place them in a list

```
DNA_list = [DNA1, DNA2, DNA3]
```

I would coerce them into a dictionary to associate the name with the raw data and result.

```
DNA_dict = dict([("DNA%i" % i, {'data': DNA, 'GC': GC_Content(DNA)}) for i, DNA in enumerate(DNA_list)])
```

Then list comprehension to get the data you want

```
name = max([(DNA_dict[key]['GC'], key) for key in DNA_dict])[1]
```

This has the benefit of allowing variable list length

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want

```
max([DNA1, DNA2, DNA3], key=GC_content)
```

---

It's not what you *asked* for but it seems to be what you *need*.