# How to log a variable's name and value?

Tags: python, variables, logging

I am looking for a way to quickly print a variable name and value while rapidly developing/debugging a small Python script on a Unix command line/ssh session.

It seems like a very common requirement and it seems wasteful (on keystrokes and time/energy) to duplicate the `variable_name`s on every line which prints or logs its value. i.e. rather than

```
print 'my_variable_name:', my_variable_name
```

I want to be able to do the following for [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str), [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#int), [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
log(my_variable_name)
log(i)
log(my_string)
log(my_list)
```

and get the following output:

```
my_variable_name:some string
i:10
my_string:a string of words
my_list:[1, 2, 3]
```

Ideally the output would also log the function name.

I have seen some solutions attempting to use `locals`, `globals`, frames etc., But I have not yet seen something that works for ints, strings, lists, and works inside functions too.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a macro...

Comment: why not using pdb : http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html ?

Comment: Evil hacks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932818/retrieving-a-variables-name-in-python-at-runtime, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python

Comment: Any good text editor should be able to define some sort of macro for generating a simple `print >>sys.stderr, "var={0}".format(var)` (or the logging construct of your choice.

Comment: Thank you for the macro and pdb suggestions. A macro might be the simplest answer. Re pdb for the small scripts I am running I find it easier to execute the program and have it automatically report it's values. Rather than repeatedly stepping and querying them in pdb.

Comment: Thank you for the evil hacks here, and below in the answers.

Comment: I have implemented a vim macro     bdwaprint '^[pa:{}:'.format(^[pa)^[

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the tool you need is only for developing and debugging, there's a useful package called [q](https://github.com/zestyping/q).

It has been submitted to pypi, it can be installed with `pip install q` or `easy_install q`.

```py
import q; q(foo)

# use @q to trace a function's arguments and return value
@q
def bar():
   ...

# to start an interactive console at any point in your code:
q.d()
```

The results are output to the file `/tmp/q` (or any customized paths) by default, so they won't be mixed with stdout and normal logs. You can check the output  with `tail -f /tmp/q`. The output is highlighted with different colors.

The author introduced his library in a lightning talk of PyconUS 2013. The video is [here](https://youtu.be/OL3De8BAhME), begins at [25:15](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OL3De8BAhME&t=1515s).

Comment: Excellent tool.  I will certainly use that in the future, thank you for pointing that out. Personally I would prefer to be able to send the output to stdout, but maybe there is an option in q for that.

Comment: @Sean I too would like to send a variable's name and value to stdout. Did you find a way?

Answer (score 14):

Since Python 3.8, using the '=' sign after the variable with a formatted f-string achieves this. For instance:

```
import pathlib as pl
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

data_root = pl.Path("D:\Code_Data_Dev\Data\CSV_Workspace_Data")

logging.debug(f'{data_root=}')
```

This outputs

```
DEBUG:root:data_root=WindowsPath('D:/Code_Data_Dev/Data/CSV_Workspace_Data')
```

Comment: This is available starting in python 3.8: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Comment: This is a great answer, but unfortunately I get a `pylint(logging-fstring-interpolation)` .

Comment: The reason for the pylint warning, and why this practice is not directly recommended (but convenient enough to use it at times), is that the string is now already formatted before the logging call happens. If the logging level is, say, warning, there is no need to format the string, and using an f-string like this is less efficient, since it'll throw away the result. The standard logging formatting only happens if the actually message will be logged.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another evil hack:

```
import inspect

def log(a):
    call_line = inspect.stack()[1][4][0].strip()
    assert call_line.strip().startswith("log(")
    call_line = call_line[len("log("):][:-1]
    print "Log: %s = %s" % (call_line, a)

b=3
log(b)
```

This obviously would need some range checks, better parsing, etc.
Also works only if the calls is made always in the same way and has probably more - unknown to me - assumptions...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way to simply get the name of a variable of a string.
you can however get the list of argument of the current fonction log.

```
import inspect

def log(a):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    args, _, _, values = inspect.getargvalues(frame)
    print "%s:%s" % (args[0], values[args[0]])
```

Comment: Nope. This is not what he is asking for.

Comment: @thefourtheye In fact you are right. this will always print "a" as the variable name...