# In Python, is there a way to print a variable's name (or expression) and its value like "foo is 123" by pr(foo)?

Tags: python

Is there a way to do this in Python, so that:

```
pr(foo)              # => foo is 123
pr(fn())             # => fn() is True
pr(obj.getVal())     # => obj.getVal() is 3.14
pr(obj.a().b.c)      # => obj.a().b.c is "hello"
pr(1 + calc() / 2)   # => 1 + calc() / 2 is 56
```

that is, print out what is being printed, as well as the value.  Some people will say this is not possible in any language, but it is in fact possible in C and Ruby.

Comment: So, you want a function that will return the variable name, and value? What have you tried doing?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is it possible in C?

Comment: more like printing it out rather than to get a string... but would they be quite similar?

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro stringification

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932818/retrieving-a-variables-name-in-python-at-runtime

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro in C you'd use a preprocessor macro with [stringification operator](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
a = 1
b = 2

def fnc():
    return 'FUNCTION'

def pr(name):
    print('{} is {}'.format(name, eval(name)))

pr('a')
pr('b')
pr('fnc()')
```

Output:

```
a is 1
b is 2
fnc() is FUNCTION
```

Comment: It'd be better to evaluate the expression in the caller's frame, so that local variables are displayed correctly

Answer (score 2):

I'd want to say: "it is impossible", which is true, for certain degrees of impossible.

There is no way to make a code macro in Python such that the usual C tricks with preprocessor stringifications and such would require.

However, you still have 2 choices:

1. if sources are available, you can make a `debug` function that would dig the line in source code where it was called using the [call frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29522250/918959). However Python bytecode only stores line numbers, not column positions on the line, so you couldn't distinguish 2 said function calls on the same line.
2. Use the `eval` trick - pass in a string that is `eval`led in the function in the caller's globals and locals, and then printed out.

The 2nd would be slightly less yuck and would be more portable as well:

```
import inspect

def pr(expr):
    calling_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    value = eval(expr, calling_frame.f_globals, calling_frame.f_locals)
    print("{} = {}".format(expr, value))
```

Elsewhere you just need to import this and you can do

```
a = 5
def func():
    b = 42
    pr('a, b')

func()
```

which prints out

```
a, b = (5, 42)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible. Python object not contains references to its names. If integers, lists, dicts and others needed to maintain a list of strings that represented names that referred to it... Imagine this!

Comment: there are tricks which make it possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/932818/retrieving-a-variables-name-in-python-at-runtime