# How to create a variable with a name containing another variable in python?

Tags: python

I have defined a variable as below:

```
time = "0915"
```

now next I want to create another variable naming it as follows:

```
x_0915 = "some value" #### idea is to have previously defined variable value in this new variable name itself
```

how do I make it automatic as I will be having this kind of multiple situations?

so the task is I want to concatenate "x" with the previously defined variable value and use it as a name for the new variable.

Comment: [have you tried this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932818/how-to-retrieve-a-variables-name-in-python-at-runtime)

Comment: You shouldn't do this. Use a *container*, like a `list` or a `dict`

Comment: Avoid dynamic variable. Use a dict only

Comment: How would use `x_0915` if it depends of the value of `time` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary instead of defining dynamic variables and creating a mess.

```py
time = ["0915", "0920", "0925"]
a = {}
for i in time:
    a[f"x{i}"] = "some value"

print(a)
```

**Output**

```
{'x0915': 'some value', 'x0920': 'some value', 'x0925': 'some value'}
```

Comment: Please paste text, not image of it

Comment: @azro I changed it, But is there any reason for the text? because image is also clear

Comment: Text is as clear as image, responsive on different device, copyable, doesn't request to load, it, will always be accessible. And why put an image a text :)

Comment: I can't paste an image into my IDE and get python to run the code.

Comment: Dictionary comprehensions can clean this up a bit:  `a = {f"x{i}": "some value" for i in time}`