# Python avoiding lambda for key which needs two callables (function composition)

Tags: python, lambda, key, max

I was working on [project euler problem 14](http://projecteuler.net/problem=14) and as a first attempt I whipped up this brute-force solution:

```
def collatz(n, memo={1: [1]}):
    if n not in memo:
        memo[n] = [n] + collatz(3 * n + 1 if n % 2 else n // 2)
    return memo[n]

def p014():
    return max(xrange(1, 10**6), key=lambda n: len(collatz(n)))
```

My question is about that lambda, I'm usually reluctant to use them but I don't know any elegant way to avoid it in this case.  Is there something in `functools` or other to chain two callables, or any other neat alternative I'm missing?

Comment: Just so it's said, you can define a regular function :)

Comment: Of course, I'm aware of that.  I was looking more for a function composition trick.  In mathematical terms, I would write it like `key=len \cdot collatz` (sorry don't know any markup for a center dot)

Comment: this is the perfect case for an anonymous function. Just use it

Comment: Why are you creating a dictionary containing the entire chains? Aren't you just interested in the chain lengths?

Comment: @JBernardo No, it's a perfect case for a higher-order function/combinator.

Comment: Writing a function composition function would be pretty simple, something like `def composite(func1, func2): return lambda n: func1(func2(n))` should work, assuming `func2` takes one argument of course. I'd agree with @JBernardo though, there's nothing wrong with the anonymous function here

Comment: @delnan I meant the "when you need two callables" case.

Comment: @Strigoides Using a lambda to avoid using a lambda? I'm not sure the OP will buy that :)

Comment: [`compose = lambda *funcs: lambda x: reduce(lambda y, f: f(y), reversed(funcs), x)`](http://ideone.com/plzPHa) (`compose()` is not recommended to use whatever implementation (the code becomes less readable))

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That's a matter of personal taste. Many functional programmers find point-free style to be much more readable.

Comment: @A.R.S. good point.  with your suggestion, i was able to get great performance boost by memoising the length rather than the sequence, and then using the simple `max(xrange(1, 10**6), key=collatz_length)`.  I am still interested in the answers to the function composition issue, though.

Comment: @Marcin: language dictates preferable style. Python is not Factor, J or Haskell. It is not just a matter of personal taste if you expect others to read your code.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Language may, to an extent, dictate style, but there's nothing inherent in a python pointfree programme that renders it less readable than e.g. in Haskell. Yes, the python programmers who will find that convenient are a subset of all python programmers, but that is also true of completely idiomatic code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be lovely if there were a `compose` function -- perhaps in `functools`. There is not, nor do I expect there will be, [alas](http://bugs.python.org/issue1506122). In the words of Raymond Hettinger,

> It has been previously discussed and rejected in other forums.  One of the issues is that the usual mathematical order is unintuitive and not self-documenting  -- i.e. is `compose(f,g)`  the same as `f(g(x))` or `g(f(x))`?  Also, it is already dirt simple to create your own compose function or to do the composition directly:  `h = lambda x: f(g(x))`.

Here are two simple [implementations](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52902-function-composition/) of `compose` as a callable class that you may find useful though:

```
# Scott Daniels, http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52902-function-composition/
# Lightly edited for style.
class Compose(object):
    '''Compose functions. compose(f,g,x...)(y...) = f(g(y...),x...))'''
    def __init__(self, f, g, *args, **kwargs):
        self.f = f
        self.g = g
        self.pending = args[:]
        self.kwargs = kwargs.copy()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.f(self.g(*args, **kwargs), *self.pending, **self.kwargs)


class Starcompose:
    '''Compose functions. Starcompose(f,g,x...)(y...) = f(*g(y...),x...))'''
    TupleType = type(())

    def __init__(self, f, g, *args, **kwargs):
        self.f = f
        self.g = g
        self.pending = args[:]
        self.kwargs = kwargs.copy()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        mid = self.g(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(mid, self.TupleType):
            return self.f(*(mid + self.pending), **self.kwargs)
        return self.f(mid, *self.pending, **self.kwargs)
```

Also, see the [`functional`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/functional/0.7.0) package, which inspired this very simple [`compose_many`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393208/577088) function of mine a while ago:

```
def compose(f1, f2):
    def composition(*args, **kwargs):
        return f1(f2(*args, **kwargs))
    return composition

def compose_many(*funcs):
    return reduce(compose, funcs)
```

Comment: Note that http://pypi.python.org/pypi/functional/0.7.0 contains a compose function.

Comment: @Marcin, thank you! I knew about that and was looking for that but it wasn't popping up in my google searches. I thought perhaps its author had removed it.

Comment: The oakwinter.com domain has expired, so the only documentation is now in the code. Not sure what's up with the author, Collin Winter.

Comment: great answer with lots of food for thought.

Answer (score 2):

It might be more pythonic to write this as a generator:

```
def p014():
    length, n = max(
        (len(collatz(n)), n)
        for n in xrange(1, 10**6)
    )
    return n
```

Comment: This is the answer to a different question.

Comment: @win: Not really - the answer is "don't use the `key` argument if it requires a lambda"

Comment: you return the max len, OP's code returns `n` for which the len is maximal -- different things.

Comment: In practice, I'd rather use this one.

Comment: After the edit, this is a nice pythonic workaround for the lacking of a function composition feature