# python sort list of lists based on inner element AND ignore case

Tags: python, sorting, ignore-case

let's say I have the following list in python

```
[ [1,"C"], [2, "D"], [3,"a"], [4,"b"] ]
```

I would like to sort the list by the letters so it would be

```
[ [3,"a"], [4,"b"], [1,"C"], [2, "D"] ]
```

To sort by the inner character, I would do `sorted(unsortedlist, key=itemgetter(1))`.
To sort by ignoring case, I would do `sorted(unsortedlist, key=str.lower)`.

How do I sort by an inner element AND ignoring case at the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's one of the (rare) use-cases for an anonymous function:

```
>>> sorted([[1, 'C'], [2, 'D'], [3, 'a'], [4, 'b']], key=lambda x: x[1].lower())
[[3, 'a'], [4, 'b'], [1, 'C'], [2, 'D']]
```

Lambdas are generally a bit clunky and unpythonic, but [unfortunately, there is no "compose" function built-in to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219320/python-avoiding-lambda-for-key-which-needs-two-callables-function-composition).

Comment: great! Worked like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Either a lambda:

```
sorted(unsortedlist, key=lambda x: x[1].lower())
```

or a regular function:

```
def my_key(x):
    return x[1].lower()

sorted(unsortedlist, key=my_key)
```