# Python: apply list of functions to each element in list

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

Say I have list with elements `content = ['121\n', '12\n', '2\n', '322\n']` and list with functions `fnl = [str.strip, int]`.

So I need to apply each function from `fnl` to each element from `content` sequentially.
I can do this by several calls `map`.

Another way:

```
xl = lambda func, content: map(func, content)
for func in fnl:
    content = xl(func, content)
```

I'm just wondering if there is a more pythonic way to do it.

Without separate function? By single expression?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the [`reduce()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) in a list comprehension here:

```
[reduce(lambda v, f: f(v), fnl, element) for element in content]
```

Demo:

```
>>> content = ['121\n', '12\n', '2\n', '322\n']
>>> fnl = [str.strip, int]
>>> [reduce(lambda v, f: f(v), fnl, element) for element in content]
[121, 12, 2, 322]
```

This applies each function in turn to each element, as if you nested the calls; for `fnl = [str.strip, int]` that translates to `int(str.strip(element))`.

In Python 3, `reduce()` was moved to the [`functools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce); for forwards compatibility, you can import it from that module from Python 2.6 onwards:

```
from functools import reduce

results = [reduce(lambda v, f: f(v), fnl, element) for element in content]
```

Note that for the `int()` function, it doesn't matter if there is extra whitespace around the digits; `int('121\n')` works without stripping of the newline.

Answer (score 1):

You are describing the basic use of a list comprehension:

```
>>> content = ['121\n', '12\n', '2\n', '322\n']
>>> [int(n) for n in content]
[121, 12, 2, 322]
```

Note you don't need the call to `strip` to convert to integer here, some whitespace is handled fine.

If your real use-case is more complex and you  wish to compose arbitrarily many functions in the comprehension, however, I found the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13219401/674039) quite pythonic:

```
def compose(f1, f2):
    def composition(*args, **kwargs):
        return f1(f2(*args, **kwargs))
    return composition

def compose_many(*funcs):
    return reduce(compose, funcs)
```