# Apply a list of functions to every item in a list?

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x

I am making a program that works on chat files under the following general form:

1. Open file & import lines (via `readlines`)
2. Do an initial pass to turn the list of strings into better-formed data (currently dicts) by:

   - Throwing out out malformed lines
   - Separating out the usernames from the text of the message
   - Throwing out lines for ignored (typically bot) users
   - Marking which lines are `/me` commands
3. Do a second pass over the list of dicts to apply various manipulations on them, such as:

   - Replacing every mention of a nick with its alias
   - Applying special formatting to `/me` commands

Rather than have multiple switches in the config file and lots of `if` statement checks within the loops, I believe the program would be cleaner if I generated the list of functions elsewhere and then fed the program the list of dicts (or strings, depending on which part of the program I'm at) and a list of functions such that the list of functions gets applied to each of the items in the list of objects.

[It seems that this probably would be a good case for list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30193572/5544691) if I were only applying a single function to each item, but I don't want to have to do a separate pass through the log for every function that I want to call.  However, [this answer notes that list comprehension probably aren't what I want, since they return a completely new list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30061021/5544691), rather than modifying in place.

---

Is my best option to have two variants of the following?

```
for item in list:
    item = a(b(c(d(item, dparam1, dparam2), cparam)), aparams)
```

(for readability, I'd put each function on its own line, like:

```
for item in list:
    item = d(item, dparam1, dparam2)
    item = c(item, cparam)
    item = b(item)
    item = a(item, aparams)
```

However, the above doesn't eliminate the need for `if` checks on all the switches and wouldn't allow for applying function `a` at two different places unless I explicitly add a switch to do so.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output as part of a [mcve]? I don't see any immediate warning signs in your current code - wrapper functions are perfectly normal in cases like this. Also, a comprehension can replace all the items of an existing list rather than creating a separate list object with e.g. `L[:] = [f(i) for i in L]`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample code, you may try this way,

```
func_list = [d, c, b, a]
for idx, item in enumerate(item_list):
    item_list[idx] = reduce(lambda v, func: func(v), func_list, item)
```

Let each func handle the data, make the loop more like pipeline.

Comment: It's generally clearer to use a loop rather than `reduce` (which is why it was relegated to `functools`): `for f in func_list: item_list[idx] = f(item_list[idx])`.