# Python how to create a dict of dict of list with defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures, defaultdict

How do I create a dict of dict of lists using defaultdict? I am getting the following error.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a=defaultdict()
>>> a["testkey"]=None
>>> a
defaultdict(None, {'testkey': None})
>>> a["testkey"]["list"]=[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: a["testkey"] is None, you can't work with it like it's dictionary

Comment: Note that even if you use a `defaultdict`, assigning something else to a key (like your `a["testkey"] = None`) will replace whatever the default is.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe I will note that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a little tricky.  You make a defaultdict of defaultdicts, like so:

```
defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
```

Comment: This is perfectly fine (up-voted), but since I have a pathology about avoiding `lambda` functions whenever possible (they're abused regularly in cases where there are always better options, e.g. using `map`/`filter` with `lambda` is _always_ slower than a listcomp/genexpr that inlines the `lambda` body; I react to said abuse by resolving to avoid them whenever possible), this approach uses the bound method of an empty `defaultdict(list)` to avoid the `lambda` and push all the work to the C layer, which (trivially, 5-10% faster) improves runtime speed: `defaultdict(defaultdict(list).copy)`

Comment: Hey, cool idea!  I hate lambda's too.  Feel free to edit it into the answer, or add your own answer.

Comment: @wim: [Sure, why not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35759455/364696)? Inflict my OCD at top-level. :-)

Comment: +1 for you.  maybe you'll enjoy my lambda-hating question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13219320/674039)

Answer (score 12):

Slightly faster than using a `lambda`:

```
defaultdict(defaultdict(list).copy)
```

This has the same observable behavior as [wim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33081175/364696), but avoids a `lambda` in favor of a (in CPython) bound built-in method implemented in C, which means default value generation doesn't have to execute any Python byte code or look up any names, and it runs a small amount faster. In microbenchmarks on CPython 3.5, it looks like the cost paid when a key did not exist at access time is about 5-10% lower this way than with the otherwise equivalent `lambda`.

Really, the reason I prefer it is because I hate `lambda` due to people overusing it when it's a bad idea (e.g. `map`/`filter` with `lambda` is always more verbose and slower than an equivalent listcomp/genexpr, but people keep doing it anyway for no discernible reason), even though in this case it hardly matters.

---

**Update:** As of 3.8, this performance improvement is gone, and the `lambda` is faster (~3% reduced runtime using `lambda` on 3.8, ~7% on 3.9), for simple microbenchmarks with `ipython`. If you wish to reproduce my tests, I tested:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> %%timeit dd = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list)); o = object
... dd[o()]

>>> %%timeit dd = defaultdict(defaultdict(list).copy); o = object
... dd[o()]
```

where caching `o = object` minimized lookup expenses and allowed us to make extremely cheap, guaranteed unique keys that we accessed (forcing auto-vivification of a `list`) while doing no other work.

The performance improvement in 3.8 is likely largely due to the introduction of [per opcode cache for the `LOAD_GLOBAL` instruction](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#optimizations), reducing the cost of looking up `defaultdict` and `list` within the `lambda` from a full `dict` lookup (two in the case of `list`, in built-ins) to a quick check of the version tag on the `dict` followed by a cheap load from the cache, reducing the cost by ~40%. The 3.9 improvement likely (not sure on this) relates to CPython's internals moving to optimize and favor vectorcall code paths more, at the expense of non-vectorcall code paths (which the `defaultdict(list).copy` path uses more of, relatively speaking), and even before these improvements, `defaultdict(list).copy` had some inefficiencies that the `lambda` lacked, providing some margin for improving on it.

Comment: Hi, could you please show your benchmarks?  I could not reproduce the speed increase

Comment: @wim: It's just an ipython microbenchmark that intentionally hammers the "auto-vivify" case, and like I said, even then, the gain is small. Just two lines `%%timeit -r5 dd = defaultdict(defaultdict(list).copy); k = itertools.count(10000).__next__`, with the "body" being just `dd[k()]`. On my machine, Linux x86-64, Python 3.5, the cost per loop is 504 ns; using `lambda: defaultdict(list)` instead is 559 ns. Like I said, not a big deal. My main motivation (such as it is, I don't actually think the `lambda` is bad here) is `lambda` hate (and hey, it's shorter too!), not micro-optimizations. :-)

Comment: You may want to qualify the performance gain mentioned in your answer by mentioning the python version.

Comment: As much as I want to like this answer, the performance gains appear to be gone.  The lambda seems to be reliably about 10% faster (CPython 3.9 on Linux).

Comment: @wim: Yup, can confirm. At a guess (educated, from code inspection) the changes are: 1) 3.8 added a per-opcode cache for `LOAD_GLOBAL` that dramatically reduced the lookup cost to find `defaultdict`/`list` for the `lambda`, and 2) The code path `defaultdict.copy` uses to copy does basically the same thing as the `lambda` (slightly cheaper than even cached `LOAD_GLOBAL`, but not by as much), but uses a C varargs based function invocation technique (`PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs`) that is more general (and slower) than the more optimized path the bytecode interpreter loop uses.

Comment: 3) The `defaultdict.copy` code path passes along a second argument to `defaultdict` (it passes the existing `default_factory` followed by `self`); even though `self` is empty, `dict.__init__` has to process it (doing nothing, but calling extra functions). The `lambda` doesn't pass that second arg, so some additional thumb-twiddling is avoided. In some future version of Python, `defaultdict(list).copy` might win again (e.g. a trivial change to `new_defdict` could make it avoid a varargs code path, recognizing a copy of an empty `dict` might get cheaper), but right now, `lambda` is faster.

Comment: @wim: I've updated the answer to include this information. I wouldn't really rely on it either way, and the improvement is trivial either way, so my original point (I hate `lambda`s because they're overused) still holds, but yes, there is no longer any performance advantage to them (not that I claimed the performance advantage was important in the first place). I did add my microbenchmark to the answer as well, so people can confirm for themselves on their own for arbitrary versions.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to do like this.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a=defaultdict()
>>> a["testkey"]=None
>>> a["testkey"]=defaultdict(list)
>>> a["testkey"]["list"]=["a","b","c"]
>>> a
defaultdict(None, {'testkey': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'list': ['a', 'b', 'c']})})
```

Comment: No, you don't, you can pass a custom function to the first `defaultdict`.

Comment: Thank you @jonrsharpe, but I tried on my console and it worked. Is that a wrong way to do this?

Comment: It will work, but it's a bit awkward to mix `defaultdict` and explicit value setting like that. Also the `a["testkey"]=None` is completely redundant.

Comment: I see. So I guess a lambda function inside a `defaultdict()` would be the best way?

Comment: Thank you @nohup for the answer, +1 for making it work, but I prefer to use it the functional way using a lambda function.