# why when building a dict of dict of which key holds list I get to see only last append?

Tags: python, dictionary

For the purpose of this question I simplified the code but basically I am parsing an oracle table and create a data map of it which I will then use later in the code. I try to save it to a dict of dicts of lists. Instead of getting a dict (e.g. dict['a']['b']) holding a list of tuples I end up having a key referencing a list with only one tuple. Last that got appended.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

somelist = ['a:b:1:2','a:b:3:4','a:b:5:6']
somehash = defaultdict(dict)

for val in somelist:
    (a,b,c,d) = val.split(":")
    somehash[a] = defaultdict(list)
    somehash[a][b].append((c,d))

for i in somehash['a']['b']:
    print i
```

I expect the output to read

('1', '2')

('3', '4')

('5', '6')

Yet I see only

('5', '6')

Comment: Because you're resetting `somehash[a]` to an empty defaultdict on every iteration?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080869/python-how-to-create-a-dict-of-dict-of-list-with-defaultdict) what you're trying to do?

Comment: would `defaultdict` not skip resetting the key if it already exists?

Comment: The append line works that way, but `somehash[a] = defaultdict(list)` will rebind `somehash[a]` each time. You need a nested defaultdict, which is addressed in the link I posted above.

Comment: @glibdud - yeah - that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

somelist = ['a:b:1:2','a:b:3:4','a:b:5:6']
somehash = defaultdict(dict)

for val in somelist:
    (a,b,c,d) = val.split(":")
    if a not in somehash: # only initiate the dict for a if it has not existed yet
        somehash[a] = defaultdict(dict)
        somehash[a][b] = list()
    somehash[a][b].append((c,d))

for i in somehash['a']['b']:
    print i
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Needed to slightly redo it though as 'b' in 'a:b' may change to c (e.g. a:c:3:4) so added this
`if b not in somehash[a]:`
to also make sure [a][b] list is defined and protect if from being overwritten at the same time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that works (based on @galibdud's link):

```
from collections import defaultdict

somelist = ['a:b:1:2','a:b:3:4','a:b:5:6','a:c:9:6','a:c:5:11']

somehash = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for val in somelist:
    (a,b,c,d) = val.split(":")
    somehash[a][b].append((c,d))


for i,k in somehash.iteritems():
    print i, ' goes with ', k
    for a,b in k.iteritems():
        print a, ' goes with ', b
        for t in b:
            print t
```

Output now reads

> ```
> a goes with defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'c': [('9', '6'), ('5', '11')], 'b': [('1', '2'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '6')]})
> c goes with [('9', '6'), ('5', '11')]
> ('9', '6')
> ('5', '11')
> b goes with [('1', '2'), ('3', '4'), ('5', '6')]
> ('1', '2')
> ('3', '4')
> ('5', '6')
> ```