# Evaluate variable names and contents

Tags: python, python-3.3

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere.  I have a list of variables, each of which represents a list.  I would like to perform an evaluation on the name of each list (i.e. its variable handle) and then use the values it contains.  Is there an easy way to do this in Python?  An example of what I mean is shown below.

```
List1 = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
List2 = ['test4', 'test5', 'test6']
List3 = [List1, List2]
for x in List3:
    if x == List1:
        do something
```

My problem is that python evaluates List1 as it's components (i.e. 'test1', 'test2', 'test3') but what I want is for it to 'do something' if x = 'List1'.

Sorry if this is confusiong, thanks for the help.  Using 3.3.

Comment: Getting the name of a variable in Python isn't something you're meant to do.  Although you can do it, with hacks, eg [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python).    But, really, you're best off re-thinking your approach to this piece of code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `is` operator

```
List1 = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
List2 = ['test4', 'test5', 'test6']
List3 = [List1, List2]

for x in List3:
  if x is List1:
    do something
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the is operator

```
x is List1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off with using a dictionary for this one. Something like this:

```
>>> list_dict = {}
>>> list_dict['list1'] = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
>>> list_dict['list2'] = ['test4', 'test5', 'test6']
>>> for a_list in list_dict:
        if a_list == 'list1':
            print(list_dict[a_list]) # or whatever you intend to do
```