# Get name of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I find myself needing to iterate over a list made of dictionaries and I need, for every iteration, the name of which dictionary I'm iterating on.

Here's an MRE (Minimal Reproducible Example).
Contents of the dicts are irrelevant:

```
dict1 = {...}
dicta = {...}
dict666 = {...}

dict_list = [dict1, dicta, dict666]

for dc in dict_list:
    # Insert command that should replace ???
    print 'The name of the dictionary is: ', ???
```

If I just use `dc` where `???` is, it will print the entire contents of the dictionary. How can I get the name of the dictionary being used?

Comment: Dictionaries do not inherently have names. Variables, as a general rule, do not inherently have names. If you're trying to get the name of the variable you assigned it to, I don't think that can be done, since you could have multiple variables pointing to the same dictionary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't use a `dict_list`, use a `dict_dict` if you need their names. In reality, though, you should really NOT be doing this. Don't embed meaningful information in variable names. It's tough to get.

```
dict_dict = {'dict1':dict1, 'dicta':dicta, 'dict666':dict666}

for name,dict_ in dict_dict.items():
    print 'the name of the dictionary is ', name
    print 'the dictionary looks like ', dict_
```

Alternatively make a `dict_set` and iterate over `locals()` but this is uglier than sin.

```
dict_set = {dict1,dicta,dict666}

for name,value in locals().items():
    if value in dict_set:
        print 'the name of the dictionary is ', name
        print 'the dictionary looks like ', value
```

Again: uglier than sin, but it DOES work.

Comment: _Don't embed meaningful information in variable names_, but variable names **are** meaningful information.

Comment: @Gabriel if the name is meaningful, it should be in a dict where you can access it. Otherwise treat it as a throwaway that's easier to remember than a memory location (it's really just a pointer to `0xFAC4928FD9` anyway)

Comment: @Gabriel any information that's actually meaningful to your program should be stored in variable data, not a variable name.

Comment: A better way of phrasing it would be "don't embed information that is meaningful _to the program_ in variable names", as it is hard to retrieve and easily broken by code changes.

Comment: @Gabriel: Also see [_Keep data out of your variable names_](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) for some good reasons not to do it.

Comment: Thanks everybody, I'll keep this information in mind.

Comment: @Gabriel don't feel too admonished. Everybody did it at some point which is why it's now so strongly suggested NOT to do that. I myself wrote a script about a year ago that had to go gather some filesize information for about 12 files each off ~100 machines to find out which machines weren't purging their history files. I designed it as `FILENAME = [('machine_name', size), ...]` for each file, and it was the biggest hackiest piece of crap script I'd ever written. I can't even use it anymore because I don't know how to maintain it anymore -- had to re-write from scratch a month ago.

Comment: The OP's question is legitimate for automation.

For example, DNA sequencing. Let's say I have 1000 samples, and for each sample, I want to compare the sample sequence with a user-specified list of input reference sequences. Instead of building a dictionary sample by sample, I can build a dictionary once for each input reference region, then for each sample, pull out the appropriate reference dictionary by name from a list of dictionaries, and compare between reference dictionary and sample. So instead of computing 1000's of dictionaries, I compute a limited list of them, just once.

Comment: @SummerEla isn't that what `functools.lru_cache` is for?

Comment: @AdamSmith I haven't seen it used in this context; but would love to see an example!

Comment: @SummerEla hmm maybe I misunderstood. I thought your concern was that you had an expensive function call that you didn't want to repeat over many many possible identical data points (which is where lru_cache shines). I guess I don't really understand your use case, and why a list of dictionaries where you have to divine the name bound to each one is superior to a dictionary of dictionaries keyed by their name?

Answer (score 4):

You should also consider adding a "name" key to each dictionary.

The names would be:

```
for dc in dict_list:
    # Insert command that should replace ???
    print 'The name of the dictionary is: ', dc['name']
```

Answer (score 3):

Objects don't have names in Python, a name is an identifier that can be assigned *to* an object, and multiple names could be assigned to the same one.

However, an object-oriented way to do what you want would be to subclass the built-in `dict` dictionary class and add a `name` property to it. Instances of it would behave exactly like normal dictionaries and could be used virtually anywhere a normal one could be.

```
class NamedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self._name = kwargs.pop('name')
        except KeyError:
            raise KeyError('a "name" keyword argument must be supplied')
        super(NamedDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def fromkeys(cls, name, seq, value=None):
        return cls(dict.fromkeys(seq, value), name=name)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

dict_list = [NamedDict.fromkeys('dict1', range(1,4)),
             NamedDict.fromkeys('dicta', range(1,4), 'a'),
             NamedDict.fromkeys('dict666', range(1,4), 666)]

for dc in dict_list:
    print 'the name of the dictionary is ', dc.name
    print 'the dictionary looks like ', dc
```

Output:

```
the name of the dictionary is  dict1
the dictionary looks like  {1: None, 2: None, 3: None}
the name of the dictionary is  dicta
the dictionary looks like  {1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'a'}
the name of the dictionary is  dict666
the dictionary looks like  {1: 666, 2: 666, 3: 666}
```

Comment: Inspired! I love it :D

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to read name and value**

```
dictionary={"name1":"value1","name2":"value2","name3":"value3","name4":"value4"}
for name,value in dictionary.items():
    print(name)
    print(value)
```

**If you want to read name only**

```
dictionary={"name1":"value1","name2":"value2","name3":"value3","name4":"value4"}
for name in dictionary:
    print(name)
```

**If you want to read value only**

```
dictionary={"name1":"value1","name2":"value2","name3":"value3","name4":"value4"}
for values in dictionary.values():
    print(values)
```

**Here is your answer**

```
dic1 = {"dic":1}
dic2 = {"dic":2}
dic3 = {"dic":3}
dictionaries = [dic1,dic2,dic3]
for i in range(len(dictionaries)):
  my_var_name = [ k for k,v in locals().items() if v == dictionaries[i]][0]
  print(my_var_name)
```

Comment: You misunderstood the question Habibur. I meant the name of the *dictionary itself*, not the keys and params inside.

Comment: Gabriel I have updated my answer  please check. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The following doesn't work on standard dictionaries, but does work just fine with collections dictionaries and counters:

```
from collections import Counter

# instantiate Counter ditionary
test= Counter()

# create an empty name attribute field
test.name = lambda: None

# set the "name" attribute field to "name" = "test"
setattr(test.name, 'name', 'test')

# access the nested name field
print(test.name.name)
```

It's not the prettiest solution, but it is easy to implement and access.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution for a descriptive error message.

```py
def dict_key_needed(dictionary,key,msg='dictionary'):
    try:
        value = dictionary[key]
        return value
    except KeyError:
         raise KeyError(f"{msg} is missing key '{key}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like `list` in R, `Record` in OCaml or `object` in JS, in Python, `dict` is just a value, not **a** key-value, and **the elements in it** are key-value, that means both of those elements have name (because the `dict` they live in will record their names) **and don't means this `dict` it self have a name**.

So, if you need to record names about some dicts or what ever anything, you shouldn't use `[]` to package them, you should use `{}` and within names you want to specify:

```py
dict1 = {... something in dict1 ...}
dicta = {... something in dicta ...}
...

dicts_dc = {'dict1': dict1, 'dicta': dicta, ...}

# means: 
# 
# dicts_dc = {
#   'dict1': {... something in dict1 ...}, 
#   'dicta': {... something in dicta ...}, 
#   ... }
#
```

Or, you can also package them by `[]`, but you should record your dicts' names inside every dict object, such as:

```py
dict1 = {'name': 'dict1', ...}
dicta = {'name': 'dicta', ...}
...

dicts_ls = [dict1, dicta, ...]

# means: 
# 
# dicts_ls = [
#   {'name': 'dict1', ...}, 
#   {'name': 'dicta', ...}, 
#   ...]
#
```

Then, for the way one, you can get their names or values by these:

```py
# get names use: 
[n for n in dicts_dc] # or: 
[* dicts_dc] # or: 
list (dicts_dc) # or: 
[n for n,x in dicts_dc.items()]

# get values use: 
[x for x in dicts_dc.values()] # or: 
[* dicts_dc.values()] # or: 
list (dicts_dc.values()) # or: 
[x for n,x in dicts_dc.items()]
```

And for the way two, you can get their names by:

```py
[x['name'] for x in dicts_ls]
```

You can see a live demo *[here](https://shinylive.io/py/editor/#code=NobwRAdghgtgpmAXGKAHVA6VBPMAaMAYwHsIAXOcpMAYgCoACAM2ICcGoIBnAdznahkGACzJlUXRAHopXMlEIBrYgDd+TADbEeGEjCkBHAK5w5AS1JcpAJgCsARgAsANgDM1x1IDmcMgFpoeD9iJj8AEzNCMgtoVmwpAHYADgAGVwBOBITbGmS0zOyAHQh6BmLi1FYzcgAKQrAACTMGMmF+OAZAXg3AYD36gEpyiAiorgB9MMIGAF4GEGKGBgByYbJ7RcRZxYAPdYZ7AF88MogF5cj5XZBF7F3FqEX9-cHK6rIa4BOWdhPqhhWxiYAXQGEBetWAjH+40IwIqVVqGjMcgYNShEz6ILBbw+zDYDAgeC2DF+aMIGDMFBgXBqfVhEDhr3eRK+DCJJPOALJKigGhM1NpmPh2MhHOhGG5vNMNLpWJqiORqNFE3FPL5NIxDPBzLxBLZJ1J5Mp-LpgyhGi40wYwHmm0CcFuKzWR0WEpMl22uwOh2OCyudod52si2drvtGyuNw2dwe+0BzyFTOAi39gNx7D1f1F5plCeAWyTocWqZZGbNXDpYFjQA)*.