# Nested dictionary with Netmiko

Tags: python, automation

My original question was answered but I am now facing another issue.

[Get index name of a list made from dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58071801/get-index-name-of-a-list-made-from-dictionaries)

I was trying to get the name of a dictionary from a list and use it in a `for` loop but it seems that it can't be done. Nested dictionaries was the solution to my issue.

Now I can successfully send command to network devices using Netmiko but it seems it only uses the last entry in the dictionary. Here's the code:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler 

site1_switches = {
    'visw0102' : {
        'device_type': 'hp_comware',
        'ip': '192.168.0.241',
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': 'password'
    },
    'visw0103' : {
        'device_type': 'hp_comware',
        'ip': '192.168.0.242',
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': 'password'
    },
    'visw0105' : {
        'device_type': 'hp_comware',
        'ip': '192.168.0.244',
        'username': 'admin',
        'password': 'password'
    }
}

vlans = {
    '300': 'TEST1',
    '310': 'TEST2',
    '320': 'TEST3',
    '330': 'TEST4',
    '340': 'TEST5'
}


for key, values in site1_switches.items():
  device_type = values.get('device_type', {})
  ip_address = values.get('ip', {})
  username = values.get('username', {})
  password = values.get('password', {})


net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type=device_type, host=ip_address, username=username, password=password)

output = net_connect.send_command_timing(
    'y', 
    strip_prompt=False, 
    strip_command=False
)
output = net_connect.send_command_timing(
    '_cmdline-mode on', 
    strip_prompt=False, 
    strip_command=False
)
print (output)
if 'Continue' in output:
    output += net_connect.send_command_timing(
        'y', 
        strip_prompt=False, 
        strip_command=False
    )
print (output)
if 'ssword' in output:
    net_connect.send_command_timing(
        '512900',
        strip_prompt=False, 
        strip_command=False
    )
print (output)
output = net_connect.send_command_timing(
    'system-view',
    strip_prompt=False,
    strip_command=False
    )
print (output)

for tag, vlan_name in vlans.items():

    output = net_connect.send_command_timing(
            'vlan' + ' ' + tag,
            strip_prompt=False,
            strip_command=False
            )
    print (output)

    output = net_connect.send_command_timing(
            'description' + ' ' + vlan_name,
            strip_prompt=False,
            strip_command=False
            )
    print (output)
```

The commands are ran successfully but only for the last entry in the nested dictionary (VISW0105). Here's the output:

```
administrator@vimgmt0103:~$ python3 test_netmiko.py
_cmdline-mode on
All commands can be displayed and executed. Continue? [Y/N]
_cmdline-mode on
All commands can be displayed and executed. Continue? [Y/N]y
Please input password:
_cmdline-mode on
All commands can be displayed and executed. Continue? [Y/N]y
Please input password:
system-view
System View: return to User View with Ctrl+Z.
[VISW0105]            <-- This is the last entry (switch) in the dictionary
vlan 300
[VISW0105-vlan300]
description TEST1
[VISW0105-vlan300]
vlan 310
[VISW0105-vlan310]
description TEST2
[VISW0105-vlan310]
vlan 320
[VISW0105-vlan320]
description TEST3
[VISW0105-vlan320]
vlan 330
[VISW0105-vlan330]
description TEST4
[VISW0105-vlan330]
vlan 340
[VISW0105-vlan340]
description TEST5
[VISW0105-vlan340]
administrator@vimgmt0103:~$
```

I am trying to figure out why it skips over the other entries. Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is as follows:

```
for key, values in site1_switches.items():
  device_type = values.get('device_type', {})
  ip_address = values.get('ip', {})
  username = values.get('username', {})
  password = values.get('password', {})
```

Everything after that is not in the loop because you un-indented it.

So from the point that the loop ends, everything refers to the last item in `site1_switches` (because that's the item on which we finished the loop).

Try simply indenting everything below that,

(i.e.

```
for key, values in site1_switches.items():
  device_type = values.get('device_type', {})
  ip_address = values.get('ip', {})
  username = values.get('username', {})
  password = values.get('password', {})


  net_connect = ConnectHandler(device_type=device_type, host=ip_address, username=username, password=password)
```

etc.)

and see what happens!

Comment: It worked! Now I feel like an idiot for not seeing it. Thank you very much!