# How to print varible name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a variable `fruit = 13`, when I `print(fruit)` I get `13`.

How do I print out the variable name so I get `'fruit'` to print out? I don't want to have to use `print('fruit')` because I will be using functions.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: So if I print out variables the people reading it will know what the numbers correspond to.

Comment: Your last sentence does not follow. Using functions just means you pass a variable to the function, and print it out using the name it's assigned to by the function declaration.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean also I am new to python

Comment: Looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python

Comment: If I have a variable that equals a number I want to print the name of the  variable

Comment: Stop repeating that and explain **why**. Names in Python are really just labels for underlying objects (see e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html); there is likely to be a much easier and more sensible way to achieve... whatever it is you want.

Comment: why not just this? `print [name for name in globals() if globals()[name] is fruit]`

Comment: If you can find it in your heart not to downvote, please do. It's not as obvious to new programmers as it is to us why this is a "bad" question. And downvoting isn't going to teach anything.

Comment: biglemon29 what @EliRose is trying to say is on Stack Overflow a question that has been asked multiple times already should not be asked again. a simple google search returns multiple ways to solve your issue. the reason why people are downvoting is probably because A. it is a duplicate question. or B. your question appears to lack any research. Next time you ask a question just make sure you have tried to find a way to do it and also try and post any attempts you have made to help the community understand where you are coming from :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve a similar behaviour by using a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and a `for`-loop [iterating through it](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

# define a dict with sample data
d = {'fruit': 13}

# print keys and values of sample dict
for key, val in d.items():
    print(key, val)
```

Output looks like:

```
fruit 13
```

Comment: Please tick my answer to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a dictionary.

```
food = {'fruit':13, 'vegetable':15}

for item in food:
    print(item, food[item])
```

Result:

```
fruit 13
vegetable 15
```

Comment: I think he wants to go backwards, finding a key with a given value.

Answer (score 0):

Just `print` the `next` key in the `locals` dictionary with the desired value. Below 13 is the value:

```
print next(k for k, v in locals().items() if v == 13) # get variable that is equal to 13
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just do this.

```
print [n for n in globals() if globals()[n] is fruit][0]

>>> fruit = 13
>>> n = None
>>> print [n for n in globals() if globals()[n] is fruit][0]
fruit
>>> b = None
>>> b = [n for n in globals() if globals()[n] is fruit][0]
>>> b
'fruit'
>>> type(b)
<type 'str'>
>>>
```

you can also make an object off of a variable in your namespace like this if you'd like

```
b = {globals()[n]: n for n in globals() if globals()[n] is fruit}
```

which you can then go and get the name text out by the value of that object

```
print b[fruit]
```

output:

```
>>> b = {globals()[n]: n for n in globals() if globals()[n] is fruit}
>>> b
{13: 'fruit'}
>>> fruit
13
>>> b[fruit]
'fruit'
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are ways to do this, (personally I think a dictionary is what you want) I'd like to explain why many people are balking at it, since on the face of it, it seems like a pretty reasonable task.

But there's a reason this is so difficult in Python (and most other languages I can think of). The reason is that, most of the time, one can think of a variable name as **shorthand** for a real, underlying *meaning* which is in your head. Most languages are designed with the idea that changing the shorthand *should not* change the output of the code.

Suppose you have code like this:

```
fruit = 10
print('Amount of fruit', fruit)
```

There are a million names we could have chosen for `fruit` -- `fruit_quantity`, `num_fruits`, etc. but one underlying concept that variable represents, which is: amount of fruit. So if you want a label for the number, use **the name of the underlying concept**.