# Getting the name of a list as a string in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

After a bit of research I found these questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)) about variables. Similarly, I would like to know if it is possible to get the **name** of a list as a *string* in Python, for example:

for a list `lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']`, a method like
    `get_name_of_list_as_string(lst)`

should return `'lst' # String`.

Is something like that even possible in Python, and if so, how exactly?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Good thing I included that link you mention as duplicated from in my original description of this question! :/

Comment: @hask.duk: Then why even ask the question if you already know the answer? There is nothing special about `list` vs. any other variable name.

Comment: @ShadowRanger As you 've said, it is all about knowing. I didn't. Hence my question.

Answer (score 10):

It's not possible; names hold references to objects, but objects do not hold references to the name(s) (if any) which reference them. It's a one-way flow of information. Remember, not all objects even have names, and many objects have more than one, so even if you did terrible things with stack inspection to try to find the name heuristically, `get_name_of_list_as_string([])` is going to fail, as will `x = [[]]`, `get_name_of_list_as_string(x[0])`.