# Automatically set results name in pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

Is there any way to get pyparsing to automatically set the `resultsName` of a grammar element to whatever it's named in my source code? That is, I would write code like

```
my_number = Word(nums)
```

and it would automatically execute

```
my_number.setResultsName('my_number')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to simply do:

```
my_number = Word(nums)('my_number')
```

using the shortcut for `.setResultsName`. Python, in general, makes it hard to [get at the *name*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python) of the variable in question.

As an alternative, if you had a list of them as a dictionary you could do something like:

```
for key,val in grammar_dict.items():
    grammar_dict[key] = val.setResultsName(key)
```

Comment: Note that `setResultsName` makes and returns a *copy* of the original expression, so be sure to use the copy when assembling lower-level expressions into higher-level ones.

Comment: Thanks. What other functions does this shortcut work with? e.g. can I write `expression = Forward()('expression')`?

Comment: AFAIK you should be able to use it for _all_ pyparsing expressions. It really comes in handy when the grammar gets complex!

Comment: You can also make a copy of an expression using just `()`, which I find useful when I want to have a specialized form of a generic expression like `quotedString` at one point in a large grammar, but I don't want to change all the other places `quotedString` is used. Like `quoted_string_of_numeric_digits = quotedString().addCondition(lambda t: t[0][1:-1].isdigit())`. This also evokes the Prototype pattern, where an existing instance is used to create new instances.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `inspect` module you can do what you want. Define a function `srn`:

```
import inspect

def srn(expr):
    """Sets the results name to the variable *name* of `expr`"""
    cf = inspect.currentframe()
    of = inspect.getouterframes(cf)[1]
    fs = inspect.getframeinfo(of[0]).code_context[0].strip()

    # name of FIRST parameter
    try:
        args = fs[fs.find('(') + 1:-1].split(',')
        n = args[0]
        if n.find('=') != -1:
            name = n.split('=')[1].strip()
        else:
            name = n
        expr.resultsName = name
    except IndexError:
        pass
    return expr
```

Then after `my_number = Word(nums)` call:

```
srn(my_number)
```

and `my_number` contains "`my_number`" as `resultsName`.

*Disclaimer 1:* This approach works well, but is quite hacky and dives deep into the Python internals, so do it at your own risk.

*Disclaimer 2:* The idea for this is not mine - I got it somewhere from StackOverflow but I don't now exactly where...