# python get referenced object name

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm not sure I'm writing my program in correct way, but I have something like this:

```
unit_dict = {}
test_dict = {'a':unit_dict}
```

Now, when I access `test_dict['a']` I get a reference (or is it pointer) to the correct dictionary, but is there a way at all to get the original object name somehow from test_dict?

Like:

```
magick_function(test_dict['a']) 
res > unit_dict = {}
```

Comment: `test_dict = {'a':unit}` do you mean `test_dict = {'a':unit_dict}`?

Comment: Yes, thanks, corrected

Comment: The second answer here might be illuminating: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Maybe there's a much simpler way.

Comment: @MKesper you are most likely correct, but that would be another question, right?

Comment: @kakk11 Many things can be done but it's not always wise to do them.

Comment: @MKesper thanks for comment, I already changed the code so I actually do not need to use this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some context, you could do something dirty with `globals()` like, but I doubt that there is not a better way for whatever you are trying to achieve in a wider context:

```
def magic(o):
  for k, v in globals().iteritems():
    if v is o:
      return k
  return None

> magic(test_dict['a'])
'unit_dict'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "change"? Reassign?