# How to convert a Python tuple to dictionary with variable name as key?

Tags: python

I would like tuple `(foo, bar)` where

```
 foo = 1
 bar = 2
```

be converted to,

```
foo_dict = {'foo' : foo, 'bar' : bar}
```

Is there an easy way to do it?

**Update:**

I see that my original post is quite misleading. So, considering `foo` and `bar` are local variables within a function scope. I'd like them to be saved to a global dictionary where the keys are their variable names.

**Re-update:**
Thanks everyone for the attention. I was using `ipywidgets.interact` to tune some parameters (passed as value), however I would like to save them globally, say in a dictionary. That's why the question comes in. Maybe for downvoters there may seem pointless to do such conversion, but do please share some hints for solve my needs pythonically.

Comment: A tuple contains values, not variables.  There is absolutely no connection between those values and the variables that held them; indeed, the value might never have been held in a variable at all, or might have been held by multiple variables.

Comment: @jasonharper I see, forgiving tuple, how could we do so for several variables then? If we have a dozen?

Comment: What is the bigger problem?

Comment: Actually I think this can be done, I just have to put the pieces together. I'm currently testing.

Comment: @MeadowMuffins Why do you need the `foo_dict`?

Comment: I think your main problem is [getting the names of variables as strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python).

Comment: @frederick99 I want to save multiple local variables in a global dictionary.

Comment: @MeadowMuffins thing is, they are already in a global dictionary. `print globals()` or `print vars()` or `print locals()`. What I've just found out though is that this really doesn't work in Enthought Canopy, which might be due to iPython.

Comment: @frederick99 I am now try to pass them like `def func(**kwargs)` so to get over this [getting the names of variables as strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python).

Comment: Your goal is getting _more_ confusing to me. Can you please edit the question to actually state what the overall aim of this is? What use do you have for such strings? Currently it looks like you're creating problems for yourself.

Comment: Is that a regular dictionary you want to add to or the `globals()` dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required function call is

```
def func(**kwargs):
    for key in kwargs.keys():
        globals()[key]=kwargs[key]
    return kwargs

foo_dict = func(foo = 1, bar = 2)
print(foo_dict)
print(foo)
print(bar)

#{'bar': 2, 'foo': 1}
#56
#hehe
```

Comment: Yep, I've just got this far too. Problem solved. I guess I posted a bad question.