# How to get a function's name as string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

In Python, how do I get a function's name as a string?

I want to get the name of the `str.capitalize()` function as a string. It appears that the function has a `__name__` attribute. When I do

```
print str.__name__
```

I get this output, as expected:

```
str
```

But when I run `str.capitalize().__name__` I get an error instead of getting the name "capitalize".

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "string_func.py", line 02, in <module>  
>    print str.capitalize().__name__
> TypeError: descriptor 'capitalize' of 'str' object needs an argument
```

Similarly,

```
greeting = 'hello, world'
print greeting.capitalize().__name__
```

gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

What went wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with `str.capitalize.__name__` or `greeting.capitalize.__name__`?

Comment: Returning error

Comment: If you want the name of the variable, you'd have to discover it separately https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python

Comment: @PeterGibson Let me check

Comment: @PeterGibson This is not what I need here

Comment: @PM2Ring I got this `TypeError: descriptor 'capitalize' of 'str' object needs an argument` using `str.capitalize.__name__`

Comment: Make sure you're not adding brackets after capitalize in that statement

Comment: @PeterGibson Okay Thanks It's solved my problem.

Comment: Do you understand why adding the parentheses causes a problem?

Comment: Not clearly get it.

Comment: @PM2Ring `capitalize().__name__` not have an attribute `__name__` it is the problem.

Comment: `greeting.capitalize` is a function object, and that object has a `.__name__` attribute that you can access. But `greeting.capitalize()` _calls_ the function object and returns the capitalized version of the `greeting` string, and that string object _doesn't_ have a `.__name__` attribute. (But even if it did have a `.__name__`, it'd be the name of the string, not the name of the function used to create the string). And you can't do `str.capitalize()` because when you call the "raw" `str.capitalize` function you need to pass it a string argument to capitalize.

Comment: @PM2Ring can I use your description comment in my question solution section?

Comment: @A.Raza Certainly!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145305/discussion-between-a-raza-and-pm-2ring).

Comment: What is the purpose of getting a function name as a string? What will you do with the name?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`greeting.capitalize` is a function object, and that object has a `.__name__` attribute that you can access. But `greeting.capitalize()` calls the function object and returns the capitalized version of the `greeting` string, and that string object doesn't have a `.__name__` attribute. (But even if it did have a `.__name__`, it'd be the name of the string, not the name of the function used to create the string). And you can't do `str.capitalize()` because when you call the "raw" `str.capitalize` function you need to pass it a string argument that it can capitalize.

So you need to do

```
print str.capitalize.__name__
```

or

```
print greeting.capitalize.__name__
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's start from the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '**name**'

Specific

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '**name**'

You are trying

```
greeting = 'hello, world'
print greeting.capitalize().__name__
```

Which will capitalize `hello world` and return it as a string.

As the error states, `string` don't have `attribute _name_`

`capitalize()` will execute the function immediately and use the result whereas `capitalize` will represent the function.

If you want to see a workaround in JavaScript,

Check the below snippet

```js
function abc(){
  return "hello world";
}

console.log(typeof abc); //function
console.log(typeof abc());
```

So, don't execute.

Simply use

```
greeting = 'hello, world'
print greeting.capitalize.__name__
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call this function and simply use **name**

```
>>> str.capitalize.__name__
```