# Compare values stored in variables, then print the variable name

Tags: python

I have tried to use the `max` code but it printed out the largest number not the variable name.

```
a=3
b=4
c=7
d=6
e=8

max(a,b,c,d,e)
```

this is the code I've tried but it printed `8` instead of `e`.
forgot to add that my values for a b c etc came from a loop so im not suppose to know their values myself...

Comment: Yes, that's what it'll do. What do you need the variable _name_ for?

Comment: Well, you'll need to call `max` on a dictionary and return the key corresponding to the largest values. Remember that names are just references to objects.

Comment: Concerning your edit: If the values come from a loop, the loop should be part of the minimal working example. How can you even assign variable values within a loop?

Comment: Don't change your question midway. That wastes everyone's time. Just close this question, accept an answer, and open a new one.

Comment: it wont let me as it says wait for 3 days

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a dictionary or a named tuple to do something like that.

```
>>> my_list = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> max(my_list, key=my_list.get)
'c'
```

Let me know if there are any other methods.

Comment: Well, you'll need to do `max(my_list, key=dict.get)`

Comment: I didn't need to. Can you try running the code?

Comment: Repeat with `my_list = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}` and see what `max` returns and what it _should_.

Comment: but if my values for a b and c came from a loop that means i myself have to work out the values and then...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Shouldn't it be `key = my_list.get`?

Comment: I get it now @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ . Thanks for your correction.

Comment: @DavidG Yep, my bad. Also, @ pissall, I didn't downvote (for the record).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 dct={'a':3 ,'b':4 ,'c':7 ,'d':6 ,'e':8}
    for i, j in dct.iteritems():
            if j == max(dct.values()):
            print i
```

Comment: That's pretty darn inefficient and somewhat inaccurate (`j` and `max(..)` must simply be equal, not _the same_, so may in fact not refer to the same entry).

Comment: Not very efficient and not pythonic, though.

Comment: If you want to use this non-pythonic way, then at least you should not call `max(dct.values())` within the loop, but once before it, then only check for equality in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python), there seems to be a way to retrieve the name of your variable (see caveat below before using):

```
a = 3
b = 4
c = 7
d = 6
e = 8

m = max(a, b, c, d, e)

for k, v in list(locals().items()):
    if v is m:
        v_as_str = k
        break

v_as_str
```

#### output:

```
'e'
```

> #### Caveat:
>
> This **may** work if you can be sure that there are no other (unrelated) variables with the same value as the max of a to e
>   somewhere in your code, and appearing earlier in the locals.
>   Thanks to @D.Everhard & @asongtoruin in the comments

Comment: Only if you can be sure that there is no other (unrelated) variable with the same value as the max of **a** to **e** somewhere in your code.

Comment: [an example](https://repl.it/NMI8/0) of what @D.Everhard is saying

Comment: Yes, I added a warning about this behavior in the body of the answer; thanks for drawing attention to it.