# python: how to access variable name from list of variable

Tags: python, variables

I want to access the variables from the list of variables to update it. I wonder if there is any way to do this with list rather than accessing variable as string described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string-in-python)

```
dWaa, dWax, dWya, db, dby = gradients['dWaa'], gradients['dWax'], gradients['dWya'], gradients['db'], gradients['dby']

for gradient in [dWax, dWaa, dWya, db, dby]:
    gradient = np.clip(gradient, -10, 10)
    # I need to update the value of variables(eg. dwaa) here

gradients = {"dWaa": dWaa, "dWax": dWax, "dWya": dWya, "db": db, "dby": dby}
```

How can I update the value of variable(eg. dwaa) inside the loop

Comment: I don't understand the question.
When you run `gradient = np.clip(gradient, -10, 10)` inside the loop, on first iteration you are updating dWax, second iteration updating dWaa and so on...

Comment: so you want eg `dWaa` to be a modified copy of `gradients['dWaa']`? Otherwise why not just modify `gradients['dWaa']` directly.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this, gradients should be a list of strings where the strings have the same name as your variables. So you could use

```
gradients = ["dWaa", "dWax", "dWya", "db", "dby"}
for gradient_name in gradients:
    gradient = np.clip(eval(gradient_name), -10, 10)
```

and manage the NameError which could be raised.