# Python Dict Assigning Key-Value in loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key-value

I have a list of variables: [var1, var2, var3, var4].

For var1, I tried the following and it works.

```
d = dict(var1=True)
f = bdd.cube(d)
```

Now I want to loop through all variables and for each variable assign the value True. 
The bdd.cube function can only take the argument d fully and not as name,value separately.

I tried to do the following, but gives me an assertion error:

> AssertionError: undefined variable "var", known variables are:{var1:3, var2:11, var3:2, var4:8}

```
for var in variables:
  d = dict(var=True):
  f = bdd.cube(d)
```

Please let me know how to do this.

The declaration of variables are as follows:

```
 Cvar           = Enum('Cvar', 'var1 var2 var3 var 4', module=__name__)

    Attributes = [CVar]
    variables = List_of_Variables(Attributes)

    def List_of_Variables(a):
      v = w = []
      for attribute in a:
        w = ['%s' %(i) for i in list(attribute)]
      return w
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: If `function_F` was `def function_F(d): print(d)`, what would be the output you expect / are looking for?

Comment: I have edited the question. I am passing the dictionary to create a bdd. So I use a standard function defined by dd library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a variable name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string)

Comment: What is the use of variable `v`?

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
for var in d:
    d[var] = True
```

`for` loop will loop through all the keys in dictionary. The variable `var` is the current key (which is a string in this case). Then, we need to set that key's value to `True`.