# Print variable name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

Here *bkd_train, bkd_test* are *dataframe.*

I wanted to print dataframe name along with it's shape.

```
for data in [bkd_train, bkd_test]:
    print("{} : {}".format(?, data.shape))
```

If i am using "data" then it's printing dataframe.

But I want o/p like this:

```
bkd_train : (10886, 12)
bkd_test : (1111,11)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot get the name of a variable as string, but you can pass a string in input and query `locals` dictionary to get the value:

```
for data in ["bkd_train", "bkd_test"]:
    print("{} : {}".format(data,locals()[data].shape))
```

it works if the variables are local. If they're global, use `globals`, with fallback on `locals`, or just `eval` (not a problem in that context since the strings to evaluate are constant)

also read: [How to get a variable name as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

I would iterate over the variable names themselves and then use `eval` to evaluate the names which will give you the dataframe.

```
for dataName in ['bkd_train', 'bkd_test']:
    data = eval(dataName)
    print("{} : {}".format(dataName, data.shape))
```