# How to get max() to return variable names instead of values in Python?

Tags: python

So I would like to get the maximum value from 3 variables, `x`,`y`,`z`.

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3
max(x, y, z)  # returns 3 but I want "z"
```

However this returns the value of `z` i.e `3`. How do I get the name of the variable e.g. `"z"` instead?

Thanks

Comment: the closest you can get is np.argmax; but that only returns the position in an array

Comment: Variables are name mappings to objects, they don't really exist as strings. What are you attempting to do?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need that information? What if multiple variables had the same value? What if one variable with the same value was never given to the max function?

Comment: You should use dictionary if you really want to get the name of maximum variable. `d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}`
 then `max(d, key=d.get)`

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/how-to-get-a-variable-name-as-a-string

Comment: I'm trying to find the mode for different categorical responses like yes, maybe, most likely, etc. So I would need the variable name since the actual value would be kinda useless.

Comment: dict = { 'a':1,'b':2, 'c':3}        # have to make a dictionary for that to print name 
                                               instead of values.
print(max(dict.keys()))            # if want to print values then dict.values()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make a dictionary and then use `max`. Also works with `min`. It will return you the variable name in the form of string.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 2
>>> z = 3
>>> var = {x:"x",y:"y",z:"z"}
>>> max(var)
3
>>> var.get(max(var))
'z'
>>> var.get(min(var))
'x'
>>>
```

Answer (score 7):

You could put them into a dictionary and use max with a key:

```
dict1 = {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}
max(dict1, key=dict1.get)
```

But think through the ramifications of this. What if you have the same val multiple times, and other edge cases.

Comment: assign `-1` to `z` and try running it again

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary and get the maximum of its items, using a key function.

```
d = {'x':1, 'y':2, 'z':3}
max(d.items(), key=lambda i: i[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all recommended but you can use the `globals()` dictionary which keeps track of all variables that are either built-ins or have been defined by the user:

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3

variables = {k: v for k, v in globals().items() if isinstance(v, int)}
max_value = max(variables.values())
res = next(k for k, v in variables.items() if v == max_value)
```

which results in:

```
print(res)  # z
```

Comment: What if in the program there are other globals with higher value than the 3 ones that we're comparing?

Answer (score -1):

After using max, you can write if statements.

```py
highest = max(x,y,z)

if highest == x:
  print('x')
```

And so forth

Comment: Print doesn't return anything which was specified

Comment: You are confusing console output with returning a string value of the variable name.  Look at the accepted answer

Comment: I did, It worked for the purposes that I needed it to work for.

Answer (score -3):

Create a List of the numbers then type max() around the list.