# Python compare two or more integer values and print out the higher one incl. the variable name

Tags: python-3.x, integer, compare

this must be a simple problem but i just cant find the right solution.

So, i've got, lets say 4 variables.

```
number1 = 10
number2 = 14
number3 = 6
number4 = 11
```

What i need is for the Programm to take all variables, compare them, and print out the highest number including the variable name.
E.G

```
"variable 'number4' has the highest number with a value of: '11'
```

There has been nothing helpful so far on the internet but i cant imagine it being that hard.
Im probably missing out on a obvious function here or something

Comment: use `max()` to get the highest value. Finding the variable name seems impossible as also stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string/18425523) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544919/can-i-print-original-variables-name-in-python).

Comment: Ye but using max() would only return "4".
I need it to remember the variable name aswell.

Example: "variable w = 4 as the highest value"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the name of a variable as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225/getting-the-name-of-a-variable-as-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as this other issue: [How to get max() to return variable names instead of values in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205011/how-to-get-max-to-return-variable-names-instead-of-values-in-python/52205185)

Basically it makes sense to convert your data structure to a dictionary instead of having individual variables.

Comment: Thats exactly it.. i couldnt find it. Sorry repost