# how to write multiple line statement to single line python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to write this below code in one line. I have lots of data. so the page goes on. So i want to shrink it. How to make it possible. I know it is possible in python. Help me with some solutions.

```
data['url']=url
data['user agent']=userAgent
data['browser']=browser
data['uniqueId']=uniqueId
data['ip']=ip
data['language']=language
and its going on.
```

I tried this but it fails.

```
data['url','user agent','browser'...] = url,useragent,browser....
```

Comment: Have you tried using newline (`\n`)?

Comment: @averwhy,Thanks for the response.. Where do i add it...(\n)

Comment: Add it where you want a line to end. Hence the name, newline

Comment: You can find other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553354/simpler-way-to-create-dictionary-of-separate-variables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
keys = ("url", "ip", "language")
values = ("http://example.com", "93.184.216.34", "en")

# if you want to update an existing dict:
data = {}
data.update(zip(keys, values))

# if you just want to create a dict:
data = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set all the values at once, you could do something like this:

```
data = { 'url': url, 'user agent': userAgent, ... }
```

If `data` already has... data, you could update it with:

```
data.update({ 'url': url, 'user agent': userAgent, ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict comprehension:

```
keys = ['url','user agent','browser']
vals = [url,useragent,browser]
data = {key:val for key,val in zip(keys,vals)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a for loop:

## Example:

```
for key, value in Data:
    finalData[key] = value
```