# Any way to stringify a variable id / symbol in Python?

Tags: python

I'm wondering if it is possible at all in python to stringify
variable id/symbol -- that is, a function that behaves as follows:

```
>>> symbol = 'whatever'
>>> symbol_name(symbol)
'symbol'
```

Now, it is easy to do it on a function or a class (if it is a
direct reference to the object):

```
>>> def fn(): pass
>>> fn.func_name
'fn'
```

But I'm looking for a general method that works on all cases,
even for indirect object references.  I've thought of somehow
using id(var), but no luck yet.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python, can i print original var name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544919/python-can-i-print-original-var-name)

Comment: I'm looking at the actual source code of NameError in python26/Python/ceval.c as obviously NameError does get the symbol name right. (As I noted below, symbol_name(non_existent) yields a traceback with "NameError: name 'non_existent' is not defined" message.) PyTuple_GetItem (and PyDict_GetItem) yields the symbol name I want, but I haven't found an interface that wraps it and reveals it to the user. So unless someone proves me otherwise, it may well be impossible. For any instance variable of a class, it is possible by overriding __getattribute__ and grepping NameError, however.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Not possible" is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is, I'm sure you can turn it into a better form =)

```
def symbol_name(a):
    for k,v in globals().items():
        if id(a)==id(v): return k
```

Update: As unbeli has noted, if you have:

```
a = []
b = a
```

The function will not be able to show you the right name, since id(a)==id(b).

Comment: >>> symbol_name(a)

'a'

>>> b=a

>>> symbol_name(b)

'a'

oops

Comment: Given that any object can have multiple names, wouldn't this be slightly better:  if a is v: results.append(k) ... (assuming you wrap the loop in an instantiation and return of "results").

Comment: still cannot tell the difference between two equal variables. Obviously, if id(x)==id(y), then symbol_name(x) == symbol_name(y), but should be 'x' != 'y'

Comment: Are you trying to provide debugging information?  Might you consider using the traceback module?  If you're trying to report "the name" of an object you might have to search through locals() and globals() and ... I'm not sure sure what other name spaces.

Comment: unbeli is right, it works not for all cases, if two variables have the same id, it may return the wrong name.

Comment: symbol_name(non_existent) yields a traceback with "NameError: name 'non_existent' is not defined" message so that NameError gets the right "name". Couldn't we use the same logic? How and where does NameError gets the "name"?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible. Even for functions, that is not the variable name:

```
>>> def fn(): pass
... 
>>> fn.func_name
'fn'
>>> b=fn
>>> b.func_name
'fn'
>>> del fn
>>> b.func_name
'fn'
>>> b()
>>> fn()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fn' is not defined
```