# List of List, want to output variable, not value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists like so:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [2, 3, 4]
c = []
append blah blah blah
```

I currently am doing:

```
for x in c:
   print(x)
```

and it is outputing [1, 2, 3]. How would i get it to output 'a' instead?

Comment: i was showing the values, in my actual document, I appended the first lists to the second.

Comment: Use `['a', 'b']` instead.

Comment: Use a dictionary: `{'a': a, 'b': b}`

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achieve what you want.  The first suggestions require using a different data structure.  The last suggestion is for demonstration purposes **ONLY** and should **NEVER BE USED**.

Option 1.  Store you data in a dictionary:

```
my_data = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [2, 3, 4]}
my_data["c"] = [my_data.get('a'), my_data.get('b')]
```

Then you would simply iterate over the key, value pairs.

```
>>> for name, value in my_data.items():
...     print name, value
...
a [1, 2, 3]
c [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
b [2, 3, 4]
```

The dictionary has no useful ordering, so if you wanted it ordered you could use an OrderedDict, or another data structure like a list of tuples.

Or you could sort them before you iterate:

```
for name, value in sorted(my_data.items()):
    print name, value
```

You could also create the dictionary after the variables are assigned

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [2, 3, 4]
>>> c = [a, b]
>>> my_data = {"a": a, "b": b, "c": c}
```

**Option Terrible**.  The very hackish way to do this (and only for demonstration purposes) is to use `locals()`

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [2, 3, 4]
>>> c = [a, b]
>>> for name, value in locals().items():
...     if len(name) != 1:
...         continue
...     print name, value
...
a [1, 2, 3]
c [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
b [2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the variable name see [Can I print original variable's name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544919/can-i-print-original-variables-name-in-python) and [How can you print a variable name in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592746/how-can-you-print-a-variable-name-in-python)

However the answers there say you should not do it.

You are telling it to print the complete contents of c which contains the objects a and b which are indeed

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
```

You are saying that you want to print the string 'a'

To do that you would have to define

```
c = ['a', 'b']
```

which is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing a. Your list c is actually

```
C = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4]]
```

If you modify a before printing c. The new values in a will be shown. As python passes by reference and c contains a reference to a