# Python print variable but not the value assigned to that variable

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of values. In some instances, I have to print names of the lists but not their values.

```
onesoil = [dates_bwn_twodates('2019-03-22','2019-04-09'),onemod]
sixsoil = [dates_bwn_twodates('4/10/2019','4/29/2019'),sixmod]
explist = [onesoil,sixsoil]

 print(explist[0])
 >>  [dates_bwn_twodates('2019-03-22','2019-04-09'),onemod]
```

Above is fine but I want to print the name but not is value.

My expected output

```
print(explist[0])
>> onesoil
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Functions are called by value, they don't get any information about the variable.

Comment: If you need names to be used at runtime you should be using dictionaries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I print original variable's name in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544919/can-i-print-original-variables-name-in-python)

Comment: Ned Batchelder has a great talk on why Python doesn't work like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns

Comment: Neiter tag of [tag:pandas] or [tag:dataframe] apply here - removed them. The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question.

Comment: Python objects retain no knowledge of the variable names that happen to be referring to them at any given time. If you require associating string objects with other objects, then you could use a dictionary object

Comment: If you want that label, the most straightforward way is to link the value to that *explicit* label with a `dict`, such as {"sixsoil": [dates_bwn_twodates('4/10/2019','4/29/2019'),sixmod] }.  Work through a `dict` tutorial to learn how to build and access these items.

Comment: def ret_var():
    return [v for v in globals().keys() if not v.startswith('_')]


i = 2
print(ret_var()[i])  #  value of i will depend on your code